# Complex valued 2+1D nonlinear PDE using NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to follow the main ideas presented in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/complex-valued-21d-pde-schroedinger-equation-numerical-method-for-ndsolve), applying it to my own problem, which is a complex, time-dependent, nonlinear PDE:

$$i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = \left[ -\nabla^2 + (|\psi|^2-1) \right] \psi$$

It is supposed to show the evolution of a vortex, so that is what I take as initial condition. The code is organized as follows

I work in 2D, on a regular grid from xl to xr and yl to yr, on the time interval [0.,tmax].

```
xl = yl = -5.;
xr = yr = 5.;
tmax = 2.;
```

This is the phase of the (complex) initial condition:

```
ClearAll[ϕ]
ϕ[x_?MachineNumberQ, y_?MachineNumberQ] := ArcTan[x, y]
ϕ[0., 0.] := 0.
```

Taking the gradient of the phase and plotting it with `StreamDensityPlot`, one can see the winding velocity of the "quantum" fluid.

[image: currents]

As for the spatial part of the initial condition, I take a Tanh profile, because the density $|\psi|^2$ in the center of the vortex should be 0, and far away it should be 1 (the equation in normalized in that way).

```
ClearAll[vortex];
vortex[x_?MachineNumberQ, y_?MachineNumberQ] := 
Tanh[4 Norm[{x, y}]] E^(I ϕ[x, y])
```

Here is the plot of the spatial profile:
[image: spatial-profile]

Now for the main part of the code, which uses NDSolve to propagate the initial condition in time, with the appropriate boundary conditions. Finally, the solution is plotted at different instances of time and an animation is created.

```
 sol = ψ /. 
       First[
         NDSolve[
           {(-1. + Abs[ψ[x, y, t]]^2)*ψ[x, y, t] - I*Derivative[0, 0, 1][ψ][x, y, t] - 
              Derivative[0, 2, 0][ψ][x, y, t] - Derivative[2, 0, 0][ψ][x, y, t] == 0, 
              ψ[x, y, 0.] == vortex[x, y], 
              ψ[xl, y, t] == 1., 
              ψ[xr, y, t] == 1., 
              ψ[x, yl, t] == 1., 
              ψ[x, yr, t] == 1.
            }, ψ, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0., tmax}, 
            Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
                       "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False,
                       "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
                            {"TensorProductGrid", 
                             "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
                             "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
                             "MinPoints" -> 100, 
                             "AccuracyGoal" -> 2, 
                             "PrecisionGoal" -> 2}
                            }]]]; 

Export["evolve.gif", pl, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "DisplayDurations" -> .1]
```

There are various errors in the output of this code. Apart from the (I hope) benign complaint about the inconsistency of the boundary and initial condition,
`NDSolve` simply chokes at t=0.02, complaining about convergency issues. I have tried playing with the parameters, but I have not found any way of circumventing this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
showStatus[status_] := 
  LinkWrite[$ParentLink, 
   SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
    ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]

xl = yl = -5;
xr = yr = 5;
tmax = 2;

ClearAll[ϕ]
ϕ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y]

ClearAll[vortex];
vortex[x_, y_] := Tanh[4 Norm[{x, y}]] E^(I ϕ[x, y])

eqn = I*Derivative[0, 0, 1][ψ][x, y, 
     t] == -Laplacian[ψ[x, y, t], {x, 
       y}] + (Abs[ψ[x, y, t]]^2 - 1)*ψ[x, y, t];

(* boundary and initial conditions should not be inconsistent. This message is not benign *)

bcs = {ψ[xl, y, t] == vortex[xl, y], ψ[xr, y, t] == 
    vortex[xr, y], ψ[x, yl, t] == 
    vortex[x, yl], ψ[x, yr, t] == vortex[x, yr]};
ics = ψ[x, y, 0] == vortex[x, y];


(* the key point here is to use the "Pseudospectral" difference order *)
nxy = 33;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ics, bcs}, ψ, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, 
   yr}, {t, 0, tmax}
  , Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {
      "TensorProductGrid"
      , "MaxPoints" -> nxy, "MinPoints" -> nxy
      , "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"
      }}
  , EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]
  ]

Animate[Plot3D[Im[sol[x, y, t]], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}], {t, 0, 
  tmax}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

You can find more information about the "Pseudospectral" difference order in [tutorial/NDSolvePDE](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the edit!

Comment: Your wellcome :), since You are posting a lot of [tag:differential-equations] etc., You may want to look at this [halirutan's script](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/5478)

Comment: The "pseudospectral" difference order, from what I understand from the docs, applies FFT methods, which basically assumes periodic boundary conditions, right? Whereas mine were fixed (Dirichlet type).

Comment: @Andrei, I think the first thing you should look at is the boundary/initial conditions. Those need to be consistent. Then one could look further how to solve the problem.

Comment: Trying you code, NDSolve chokes with the error "Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 1.92". Also, could you please edit your answer to plot Abs[sol]^2 instead of the imaginary part please? That is the physical quantity of interest ;)

Comment: About the boundary conditions, what I can say based on physical arguments is that far away from the center (at infinity), the solution tends to 1.

Comment: @Andrei, `MaxSteps->Infinity`

Comment: @andrei, the question was not about plotting the solution, you did not provide any code for that, so I leave it up to you form the solution you need.

Comment: i did in the original post, but somehow it got lost in the editing :) well nevermind that, the real problem indeed are the boundaries, because it seems like there is reflection there, and I need to simulate the system as if it were infinite

Comment: "Simulating as if it were infinite" is a very difficult task in general. It may be easiest to just extend the spatial domain so that boundary effects don't kick in until after `tmax`...

Comment: @ruebenko, could you please clarify one thing? in your answer, are the boundary conditions assumed to be periodic or not? because in the documentation, for the "pseudospactral" difference order, it looks like that! I am asking because I wanted mine to be fixed..

Comment: @Andrei, `Plot[vortex[xl, y] - vortex[xr, y], {y, yl, yr}]` and `Manipulate[
 Plot[Chop[sol[xl, y, t] - vortex[xl, y] + 1], {y, yl, yr}], {t, 0, 
  tmax}]` ;-)

Comment: @Andrei, but Infinity is not 5!