# PoincareSection for a driven damped pendulum is not generating a Poincaré section at all, why?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

So I have the general code from the `PoincareSection` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/EquationTrekker/ref/PoincareSection.html) that is changed up for a Driven Damped Pendulum:

```
coupledDiffEq = 
 {ω'[t] == -(1/q) ω[t] - Sin[θ[t]] + 
  g*Cos[ϕ[t]],
  θ'[t] == ω[t],
  ϕ'[t] ==  Drive};

data = Block[{q = 3.9, g = 1.5, Drive = 1}, 
Reap[NDSolve[{coupledDiffEq, 
θ[0] == 0, ω[0] == 0, ϕ[1] == 2*Pi, 
WhenEvent[Mod[ϕ[t], (2*Pi)] == 0, 
Sow[{θ[t], ω[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 100000}, 
MaxSteps -> ∞]]][[-1, 1]];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, All}]
```

Then I `ListPlot` data and it comes out as not a `PoincareSection`. Often it looks like a phase plot more than anything else. I have attempted to change the

```
Mod[ϕ[t], DriveFrequency]
```

where `DriveFrequency` should be `Drive / (2*Pi)`, but that often does nothing. The system of equations evaluates and produces points, they just are random though. How do I get a nice Poincaré section with this?

[image: my result]

I am getting this when I should be getting

[image: correct Poincaré section]

Comment: Yes, when I use the Parameters (q = 3.9, g =1.5, Drive = .6667) I get something that looks more like a phase diagram. Imager Link to result: http://imgur.com/8natnP0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

`J.M.` has some good comments, so I'm going to implement them.

```
coupledDiffEq = {θ''[t] == -(1/q) θ'[t] - 
 Sin[θ[t]] + g*Cos[ϕ[t]], ϕ'[t] == drive};

data = Block[{q = 3.9, g = 1.5, drive = 2/3}
   , First@Last@Reap@NDSolve[{
        coupledDiffEq, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 0, ϕ[1] == 2 π
        , WhenEvent[Mod[ϕ[t], 2 π] == 0, Sow[{Mod[θ[t], 2 π, -π], θ'[t]}]]
        }, {}, {t, 0, 100000}, MaxSteps -> ∞]
   ];
ListPlot[Drop[data, 100]]
```

I dropped the first 100 points to make sure that we aren't capturing any of the transients.

---

I played around with your code, and couldn't get it to do what I wanted, so I went this route instead. Note that you need to move `θ[t]` back into the interval `-π` to `π` in order to get the attractor, and you should *not* use `ListLinePlot`, because you will get a mess.

```
ClearAll[coupledDiffEq, ω, q, θ, g, ϕ, drive]
coupledDiffEq := {ω'[t] == -(1/q) ω[t] - Sin[θ[t]] + g*Cos[ϕ[t]], θ'[t] == ω[t], ϕ'[t] == drive};

sols = Block[{q = 3.9, g = 1.5, drive = 2/3}
  , First@NDSolve[
     {coupledDiffEq, θ[0] == 0, ω[0] == 0, ϕ[1] == 2*π}
     , {θ[t], ω[t]}
     , {t, 0, 100000}
     , MaxSteps -> ∞
    ]
 ];

 data = Table[{Mod[θ[t] + π, 2 π] - π, ω[t]} /. sols, {t, 20*(2 π)/(2/3), 100000, (2 π)/(2/3)}];
 ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

This code should work too, more along the lines of what you did:

```
coupledDiffEq = {ω'[t] == -(1/q) ω[t] - Sin[θ[t]] + g*Cos[ϕ[t]], θ'[t] == ω[t], ϕ'[t] == drive};

sols = Block[{q = 3.9, g = 1.5, drive = 2/3}
  , First@Last@Reap@NDSolve[{coupledDiffEq, θ[0] == 0, ω[0] == 0, ϕ[1] == 2 π
  , WhenEvent[Mod[ϕ[t], 2 π] == 0, Sow[{Mod[θ[t] + π, 2 π] - π, ω[t]}]]
 }, {θ[t], ω[t]}, {t, 0, 100000}, MaxSteps -> ∞]];

ListPlot[sols]
```

[image]

Comment: Two notes: 1. As I noted in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89767), you can pass an empty list as the second argument of `NDSolve[]` so that it doesn't save the `InterpolatingFunction[]` objects, potentially saving memory. OP seems to have tried this, but could not make it work. 2. `Mod[θ[t] + π, 2 π] - π` is slightly more compactly done as `Mod[θ[t], 2 π, -π]`.

Comment: You are amazing! Its quite interesting how you have to play around with Sow[...] and θ[t] to get this to work! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Escap3faith, BTW, you don't really need `ω` for your system (assuming you only used it as a temporary intermediate); `NDSolve[]` can handle `θ''[t] == -θ'[t]/q - Sin[θ[t]] + g Cos[ϕ[t]]` perfectly, and your `Sow[]` becomes `Sow[{Mod[θ[t], 2 π, -π], θ'[t]}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for comments and links! I actually couldn't think of a good reason why not to actually solve for the functions, but not returning a memory-intensive `InterpolatingFunction` is a good one. I will modify the post with your comments, I think, to make the answer more worthwhile.

Comment: @J.M. I don't think I do, but I was reading a paper and they broke it down into 3 equations due to the necessity of ϕ[t], and I just followed out of frustration for the project. I'm 100% positive I don't need all 3 coupled equations because Mathematica has the power to deal with them, but rather just the 2. Paper: http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~gasenzer/index.php?n1=teaching&n2=chaos

Comment: @Escap3faith, next time you ask a question, you'll want to mention references like those; they will help answerers a great deal when helping you.