# NDSolve: Improperly assigned stepsize

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

> This is not a question which I estimate is aided in answering by providing complete code, which is excessively long.

I ran an `NDSolve[]` at `MachinePrecision`, with the specification `MaxSteps -> ∞`. I then plotted the step size used:

```
ListPlot[stepsd, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Step size]

I thought the step size was disconcertingly high, especially since I was trying to eliminate numerical errors in the output yet the `NDSolve[]` ran very fast:

```
AbsoluteTiming[s = NDSolve[Flatten[{xf, yf, zf,vel, pos}], Flatten[{xt, yt, zt}], {t, 0, time}, MaxSteps -> ∞];]
```

> {0.748079, Null}

Consequently I decided to make a graph of the end numerical error (I know the real values to 17 digit precision at the end point) in relation to `MaxStepSize ->α`:
Note that this is error of the form $$\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y+\sigma^2_z}$$

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{α, σ}]]
```

[image: error per max stepsize]

As you can see the error plummets to about one third, and stays there when the `MaxStepSize` is reduced to `0.5` or lower, at which point I suspect the model error starts to dominate (the model is of course not perfect). The timing for `0.5` is:

> {1.20144, Null}

As the starting values used for this part are between $O[1]$ and $O[-4]$, and are given with 17 digit precision (though *Mathematica* registers the dataset at `MachinePrecision`, I'm surprised this numerical error is allowed as the documentation centre claims that:

> NDSolve adapts its step size so that the estimated error in the solution is just within the tolerances specified by PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal.

Am I missing something, or did the `NDSolve[]` fail to accurately pick an appropriate `MaxStepSize`?

Comment: Can you at least mention what kind of ODEs are you solving?

Comment: It's not clear the 2nd plot indicates the condition "that the estimated error in the solution is just within the tolerances specified by PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal" is violated. (1) `NDSolve` uses [``NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[2, {10.^-pg, 10.^-ag}]``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveVectorNorm.html), (`pg`, `ag` = `PrecisionGoal`, `AccuracyGoal` settings resp.) to measure the acceptability of the estimated error. (2) The estimated error is an estimate, and not guaranteed to bound the actual error. -- Some clarification about how `σ` is computed would be helpful.

Comment: @J.M. The solar system model mentioned in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121035/mass-distribution-in-ndsolve
Though I've converted to `AU` and `day` units.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I calculated the distance {at a time period of a body (specifically Earth) } between the expected position, and the position that the model computes at that point.
It was my (maybe naive) belief that in theory the error should not exceed `Precision` which is half `WorkingPrecision`.
Am I to understand that with the available information it cannot be guaranteed that the model delivers 7-digit precision as I expected?

Comment: @Feyre (1) What controls the step size depends on which is bigger, `10.^-pg * * solution` or `10.^-ag`: In the first case, relative error will dominate, and in the second, absolute error will dominate. When they're about the same, then the (absolute) error tolerance will be about two times `10^-ag`.  (This is just a consequence of the formula in the tutorial I linked above.) So the answer to your question depends on whether you're talking about absolute or relative error (if the solution has a numerical magnitude of about `1.`, then they're roughly the same).

Comment: @MichaelE2 The solution has three components, $x,y,z$, the first two fluctuate beween magnitude `1` and value`0`, the z component stays in the `-4` order for the duration of this calculation. However it is the x and y components that have the higher order errors.

Comment: (2) Strictly speaking the error estimate is just an estimate, so it is not *guaranteed* to be accurate, but *usually* it is. It depends on the system, and I would think that for yours, it should be pretty good. Rounding error is a separate issue (from truncation error, the inherent error of the discrete integration method used by `NDSolve[]`), and that sometimes is a problem. For this sort of problem, a symplectic integrator is often used; see [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html).

Comment: I guess I should mention that it is *local* error that `NDSolve` controls.  If you have many steps, those errors can add up if they're mainly in one direction.

Comment: Well it's an orbit, in fact I'm evaluating one sidereal year. I'll read up on the info you've given and consider the matter settled, and accept this is just one of those things in which human intervention is required.