# How do I truncate an interpolating function?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have a very large interpolating function and want access the function at one point in time.

I am running out of `RAM` running `NDSolve`. I am considering exporting the last time instance of `NDSolve`, so that I can continue the running it, using those final conditions as the initial conditions of the next run.

I just want to create an interpolating function for the final time, T.

How would I go about this?

Here is part of the code that performs this operation:

```
(* Numerically Solve the PDEs *)

ndsolve = NDSolve[ pdes3, {A, B, C},
    {x, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, T}]
```

I want to continue it with the following in the next run:

```
ndsolve = NDSolve[ pdes3, {A, B, C},
    {x, -L/2, L/2}, {t, T, 2T}]
```

Comment: I believe that [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31100/731) may help you. There are two other answers that both use that `NDSolve` can be made to only return the solution for given points. From my experiments with `MaxMemoryUsed`, however, that does not seem to reduce the memory usage.