# How to use NDSolve with limited RAM?

Tags: differential-equations, export, import, interpolation

How can I use `NDSolve` when running out of RAM?

The code I am implementing:

```
sol = NDSolve[ pdes, {A, B, C},
    {x, -L, L}, {t, Tf, Tf} ]
```

in order to obtain the end solution of `NDSolve` to be exported to the next run (due to limited RAM).

In previous attempts the solution of `NDSolve` was exported as an interpolating function, such as:

```
Export["sol_Tf.wdx",sol]
```

`sol_Tf.wdx` is the export file of the `NDSolve` run.

Also see my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204420/how-do-i-truncate-an-interpolating-function).

I then imported it as:

```
Import["sol_Tf.wdx"]
```

and used the boundary conditions:

```
A[x, Ti] == A[x, Tf]
B[x, Ti] == B[x, Tf] 
C[x, Ti] == C[x, Tf]
```

But the results were different from running it all in one go. What went wrong here? Is there a better way of doing this?

For example, in the heat equation:

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0,
u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

I would want to continue it with the end results of the previous run, as the new boundary conditions of the next run; RAM free, and by running it again from t = 10 to t = 20.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you added a simple PDE exmaple such that people can experiment with this. As the question stands now, I'd first need to come up with an example to try this.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the [`NDSolve` Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) tutorial to control the memory usage and save down the state of intermediate runs.

Initialise the `` NDSolve`StateData `` for the complete range you need to create solutions. Below is done for `0 <= t <= 30` and I will iterate in chunks of 10.

```
ndsStateData = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
    {
     D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
     u[0, x] == 0,
     u[t, 0] == Sin[t],
     u[t, 5] == 0
     },
    u,
    {t, 0, 30}, {x, 0, 5}
    ];
```

Next I iterate in 3 chunks of 10.  `ndsStateData` can be saved down after the current chunk's solution is extracted with `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions ``.  Below I reassign  `ndsStateData` with the reinitialised `` NDSolve`StateData `` instead.

```
sols = {};
Module[{step = #},
    NDSolve`Iterate[ndsStateData, {(step - 1)*10, step 10}];
    AppendTo[sols, u /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndsStateData]];
    ndsStateData =
     First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[ndsStateData, {u[step 10, x] == sols[[step]][step 10, x]}];
    ] & /@ Range@3;
```

`sols` contains the 3 solutions over each chunk. Notice the difference in the domains.

```
sols
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting the solutions.

```
Plot3D[sols[[#]][t, x], {t, (# - 1) 10, # 10}, {x, 0, 5},
    PlotRange -> Full,
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[109][#]
    ] & /@ Range@3 // Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you make a gif of you rotating the figure?

Comment: @DerekH I used ShareX.

Answer (score 4):

The following throws some inconsistency warnings, but appears to work (i.e., no obvious discontinuities at the seam).  Also, I did not change the boundary condition, but I fed the final condition of the first solution to the "initial" condition of the second solution.

```
uif1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
    u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}];
uif2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
    u[10, x] == uif1[10, x], u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, 
   u, {t, 10, 20}, {x, 0, 5}];
plt1 = Plot3D[uif1[t, x], {t, 0., 10.}, {x, 0.`, 5.`}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 5}, {-1, 1}}];
plt2 = Plot3D[uif2[t, x], {t, 10.`, 20.`}, {x, 0.`, 5.`}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 5}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.22`, 1.`, 0.44`]];
Show[{plt1, plt2}]
```

[image: Seamed Solutions]