# How to discard NDSolve`StateData intermediate data

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'd like to prepare the equations with `NDSolve'ProcessEquations` and then doing repetitive `NDSolve'Iterate` for the steps.

I need only variable values at each step, not the final InterpolatingFunction and the computation may run indefinitely.

Is it possible to discard state data for processed steps?

Comment: ``NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y’[x]==y[x],y[0]==1`, y, {x, 1, 2}]`` will save only the solution between `x==1` and `x==2`, I think.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think this comment should be an answer.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31100/5467)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought this was described in some `NDSolve` tutorial, but I can't find it.  It is mentioned in [Only final result from NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31094/only-final-result-from-ndsolve), which @andre314 linked in a comment.

The call

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y’[x] == y[x], y[a] == 1}, y, {x, b, c}]
```

with an initial condition at `x == a` and interval `b <= x <= c` will save only the solution between `x == b` and `x == c`.  The end points `b` and `c` may be the same, in which case only the solution at `x == b` will be saved.

Since I couldn't find documentation, I tested it empirically (see below).  With a call of the form

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[ivp, y, {x, x1, x1}]
```

the user is responsible for storing solution data after each call to `` NDSolve`Iterate[] ``.  The data will be discarded with the next call that advances the integration time front.

**Appendix: Empirical evidence**

First call: save the whole solution.

```
Quit[]

Block[{n = 30},
 char = Times @@ Table[(m^2 + k), {k, 1, n}]; {state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{CoefficientList[char, m] . 
      Table[Derivative[k][y][x], {k, 0, 2 n}] == 0, 
    Table[Derivative[k][y][0] == 1, {k, 0, 2 n - 1}]}, y, {x, 0, 300},
    MaxSteps -> 10^5]
 ]
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 0.01] (* initialize the iteration loop *)
mu = MaxMemoryUsed[];
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 300]
MaxMemoryUsed[] - mu
```

> ```
> (*  13558848  *)
> ```

Second call: save only the endpoint.

```
Quit[]

Block[{n = 30},
 char = Times @@ Table[(m^2 + k), {k, 1, n}]; {state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{CoefficientList[char, m] . 
      Table[Derivative[k][y][x], {k, 0, 2 n}] == 0, 
    Table[Derivative[k][y][0] == 1, {k, 0, 2 n - 1}]}, 
   y, {x, 300, 300}, MaxSteps -> 10^5]
 ]
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 0.01](* initialize the iteration loop *)
mu = MaxMemoryUsed[];
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 300]
MaxMemoryUsed[] - mu
```

> ```
> (*  12432  *)
> ```