# How to prevent NDSolve to store result for each time step?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

It's very painrful especially using FEM that Mathematica gives a solution for transient Navier-Stokes equation  at each time step. Is it possicle to control output? This is my code:

```
Ω = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
 RegionUnion[
  Flatten[Table[
    Disk[{n, m}, 1/16], {n, -1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {m, -1/2, 1/2, 1/2}]]]];
op = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
   10^-3 Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
     u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] - y Tanh[t], 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
   10^-3 Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
      y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
     v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y] + x Tanh[t], 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]};
bcs = 
  {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, True], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == 1 && y == 1]};
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};
Monitor[
  AbsoluteTiming[
    {xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
      NDSolveValue[
        {op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, {t, 0, 5},
        Method -> 
          {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
            {"MethodOfLines",
             "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
               {"FiniteElement", 
                "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.002, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.02}, 
                "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];], 
  currentTime]
```

If we look at data grid of the solution

```
Dimensions[xVel[[4]]]
{494, 2, 10492}
```

So it returns the whole data (values at all mesh points for each time step). It takes a lot of memory if simulation is long. I don't want that Mathematica accomelates results at each time step.  I need snapshosts of the flow, say at 10 ( instead of 494) time points.  What should I do for that?

Comment: Can you show an example with code?

Comment: Try `NDSolve[{x''[t] == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 2, 2}]`. (Note the time interval.) It's in the docs somewhere, but I can't find it right now.  You can also accumulate solution data for a subinterval `{t, 1, 2}`.

Comment: Apparently I couldn't find it a couple of months ago either: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238226/4999

Comment: If you need less accuracy, why not reduce the accuracy goal?

Comment: NDSolve[{x''[t] == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x[2], {t, 0,2}] returns only the last timestep!

Comment: @MarcoB I add my example with code.

Comment: @user21 I want to keep the accuracy of simulations.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann no, I need evolution but with lower resulution.

Comment: @ RodionStepanov I Think my answer is what you are looking for. For example  `NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, {x[1], 
  x[2]}, {t, 0, 2}]` gives the solution at two times, accuracy and resolution isn't affected!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Check the memory usage. I don't know for sure (things change), but I thought that form would save all the intermediate steps until the end, and then return only the desired values and throw the rest away.

Comment: Yes, it still saves all the steps and just chage the output. Unfortunatly it does not help but thanks any way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 What a pity! I also thougt   to use `NDSolve\`ProcessEquations` (your comment&link) but I don't know how to split the coodinates `t` and the spatial coordinates...

Comment: The time steps for your example code are quite large, just as it is. I believe I have a way to do what (I think) you're requesting. But it saves very little in the case you posted. Even if I extend the interval to `{t, 0, 100}`, there are only 32 steps.  The start-up overhead tends to dominate the marginal increase in memory per step. With so few steps, it's hard to decrease the number of steps saved in order to show any significant memory savings.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding your request: You'd like to have an interpolating function that does not use all data points computed but still have the same accuracy compared to a interpolating function that makes use of all computed data points?

Comment: @user21 My interpretation led me to do the following: Use ``NDSolve`Iterate`` to advance the time integration to a sequence of specified time stops; at each stop, harvest the `"SolutionData"`. This can be used to construct a sequence of interpolations over the spatial discretization, one for each time stop. I wasn't going to worry about interpolation over time unless specifically requested. The sequence would be useful for illustrating the evolution of the system while saving memory.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've changed the problem. Now silumation lasts 3 mins and produces  494*10492 grid.

Comment: @MichaelE2, that's certainly the approach I would think is most promising. One could go ahead and then plug these stop times into an `ElementMeshInterpolation` to get a single interpolating function. But I am not sure about the overall accuracy of this approach, because the time stepper does not store unnecessary data, I would think. But I am interested to see what comes out of this.

Comment: @user21 I think it will not help because interpolating function is about final stage of simulation. I need to find a way to say Mathematica to accomulate during iteration only certain steps (not all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry just to drop code, but I'm bit too busy at the moment to write up a presentation.  Hopefully the code with still be helpful.  Ask questions and I'll try to address them later.

The testing setup (testing memory usage). Execute this each time after quitting kernel, before running memory usage tests below:

```
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
   RegionUnion[
    Flatten[Table[
      Disk[{n, m}, 1/16], {n, -1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {m, -1/2, 1/2, 1/2}]]]];

op = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
    10^-3 Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . 
     Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] - y Tanh[t], 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] + 
    10^-3 Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . 
     Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y] + x Tanh[t], 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y]};
bcs = {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, True], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == 1 && y == 1]};
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};

(* Hold the NDSolveValue call; release in the two test phases *)
ndscall = Hold[
    NDSolveValue
    ][{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, 
    p}, {x, y} ∈(*emesh*)Ω, {t, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.002, 
           "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.02}, 
         "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];
```

Memory usage of accumulating the whole solution:

```
Quit[]

(* initialize before executing this cell *)
mem0 = MaxMemoryUsed[];
Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
    ReleaseHold[ndscall];], currentTime] (* takes ~100 sec *)
MaxMemoryUsed[] - mem0

(*  560095104  > 183063416 below *)
```

Memory usage of saving the solution data at `t = 0, 1, 2,...5`:

```
Quit[]

(* initialize before executing this cell *)
mem0 = MaxMemoryUsed[];
{state} = (* change time interval from {t, a, b} to {t, b, b} *)
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations @@ (ndscall /.
     {t, a_, b_} :> {t, 
       tinitial = a; b, tfinal = b});
mem1 = MaxMemoryUsed[];
Monitor[
 sol = Table[
    NDSolve`Iterate[state, t0];
    memused[t0] = MaxMemoryUsed[] - mem1;
    state@"SolutionData"["Forward"],
    {t0, Subdivide[tinitial, tfinal, 5]}(* time stops *)
    ];,
 currentTime]
MaxMemoryUsed[] - {mem0, mem1}

(*  {183063416, 82331096}  < 560095104 above *)

AssociationMap[memused, Subdivide[tinitial, tfinal, 5]]

(* memory usage once NDSolve`Iterate loop starts:
     Once Iterate starts, each step adds only a few hundred KB
  <|0 -> 0,        1 -> 80771560, 2 -> 80771560,
    3 -> 81510592, 4 -> 81717312, 5 -> 82331096|>
*)
```

Processing the solution data.  I'm not sure yet that I've figured out the best workflow here.  This code processes the last time stop (`sol[[-1]]`) only, to compare with the final solution

```
Needs@"NDSolve`FEM`";
meshes = Through[
   NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X"][
     "ElementMesh"] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]];
pts = Length /@ Through[meshes@"Coordinates"];
puvVals = TakeList[
   NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[sol[[-1]], "X"],
   pts];
puvSol = MapThread[#1 -> ElementMeshInterpolation[#2, #3] &,
  {NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X"],
   meshes,
   puvVals}
  ]
```

Check last solution data (`puvSol`) with solution (from `ProcessEquations[]`):

```
soltf = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
Differences@{v["ValuesOnGrid"] /. soltf // First, 
   v["ValuesOnGrid"] /. puvSol} // MinMax

(*  {0., 0.}  *)
```

Summary.  Set up the computation with `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` and a time integration interval of the form `{t, tf, tf}`, where `tf` is the final time.  Advance the integration with `` NDSolve`Iterate `` to desired time stops at which the solution is desired. Harvest that data from the state object returned by `ProcessEquations`.

```
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs, ic}, 
   {u, v, p}, {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
   {t, 5, 5},    (***  N.B. No intermediate data saved  ***)
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.002, 
           "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.02}, 
         "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}}}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])]

sol = Table[
 NDSolve`Iterate[state, t0];       (* advance the time integration *)
 state@"SolutionData"["Forward"],  (* harvest solution data *)
 {t0, {t1, t2, ...}}               (* time stops *)
 ]
```

The solution data contains the function values in a flat list, which needs to be subdivided and mapped onto the `ElementMesh` for the spatial domain.

Comment: This is working sheme. Thanks a lot.