# Integrating over an interval

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, output-formatting

I have a function I want to integrate, which is $v(t)$.

```
solv = NDSolve[{v'[t] + (v[t])^2 + f == 0, v[0] == -I*k55}, 
v[t], {t, 0, 150}]
```

Also, I have a range `tRange=[0,150,0.001]`. Now, what I want to do is to integrate this function `v=v[t]/.solv` using the range I proposed. For example, say `x1` and `x2` are in the range, and `xmin=0`, `xmax=150`; how do I integrate `v` from `xmin` to `x_1`, then `x_1` to `x_2`, then so on until `xmax` with `0.001` of difference between each step. At the end, I want to put everything in a table. Is there any way how? Or is it possible to make a `For[]` loop to get the results?

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 3 x'[t] Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] 
Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] + 
Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, 
a'[t]/a[t] == Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4],
τ'[t] == 1/a[t],
x'[0] == -0.008226306418212731,
x[0] == 5.630991866033891,
a[0] == 1,
τ[149.4517772937791] == 0},
{x, τ, a},
{t, 0, 500}]
a = a[t] /. sol;
\[Tau] = \[Tau][t] /. sol;
x = x[t] /. sol;
xt = x'[t] /. sol;
att = a''[t] /. sol;
tEnd = t /. FindRoot[(att == 0), {t, 0, 150}]
aEnd = a /. t -> tEnd;
H = Sqrt[(xt)^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x*Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4];
V = 3/4 (1 - Exp[-Sqrt[2/3] x])^2;
Vt = Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x Sqrt[2/3]]);
Vtt = -Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3]*x]*(Exp[Sqrt[2/3]*x] - 2);
t55 = t /. FindRoot[(aEnd/a == E^55), {t, 0, 150}];
\[Tau]55 = \[Tau] /. t -> t55;
a55 = a /. t -> t55;
eps1 = (1/2) (Vt/V)^2;
eta = Vtt/V;
eps2 = -4 eps1 + 2 eta;
k55 = a55*(H /. t -> t55);
\[Nu] = 3/2 + eps1 + 1/2*eps2;
f = k55^2 - (\[Nu]^2 - 1/4)/(\[Tau]^2);
```

Comment: `k55` is undefined

Comment: Sorry @UlrichNeumann, let me give the definitions.

Comment: Try `V= NDSolve[{v'[t] + (v[t]^2 + f == 0, v[0] == -I*k55}, 
v[t], {t, 0, 150}]`:  `V[x2]-V[x1]`

Comment: It would be simpler to call NDSolve with a maximum step size option of 0.001, and let NDSolve decides itself where the steps are. Do you really need the steps to be at multiples of 0.001 ?

Comment: Try `V= NDSolve[{v'[t] + (v[t]^2 + f == 0, v[0] == -I*k55}, 
v[t], {t, 0, 150}]`:  `MapThread[V[#2]-V[#1&,{Rest[trange],Most[trange]}]`

Comment: @andre314 That would be great, but only if you could integrate inside the `NDSolve`. I am interested in the integration part since I have already solved for `v`. However, it would be preferable if I could just get the antiderivative of `v` through an `Integrate[]` function.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Would it show me the integral of `v`? It seems more like just the difference of two numbers of `V`.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT AN ANSWER**
(Too long for a comment,
and I'm not sure to understand your aim.)

It would be simpler to call NDSolve with a maximum step size option of 0.001, and let NDSolve decide itself where the steps are.

Here is an example :

I don't copy `k55` and `f` that are defined in your large block of code.

```
x1 = 10;
x2 = 20;
x3 = 30;
xmax = 150;

stateData = 
  First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{v'[t] + (v[t])^2 + f == 0, 
     v[0] == -I*k55[[1]] (* and not k55 *)}, v[t], t, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]];

res = Table[NDSolve`Iterate[stateData, t];
  varAndDerivativesValues = 
   NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[stateData, "Forward"];
  stateData = 
   First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[stateData, 
     Equal @@@ Most[varAndDerivativesValues]];
  varAndDerivativesValues, {t, {x1, x2, x3, xmax}}]
```

[image]

The integration stops at t=138 due to another problem not related with the question :

[image]

[Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31100/5467)

Comment: I was thinking something more like `For[i = 0, i <= 138.999, j = i + 0.001, 
 Integrate[v[t], {t, i, j + 1}]]`, would it work? I just want to integrate `v`.

Comment: I don't understand your code `For[...]`. I have not used `For[]` since 20 years and your syntax probably have some missing or implicits that I can't guess.

Answer (score 0):

The block which evaluates `k55, f` can only be executed once without an error message. Strange, don't know why.

Change the last codelines to

```
k55 = (a55*(H /. t -> t55))[[1]];
\[Nu] = 3/2 + eps1 + 1/2*eps2;
f = (k55^2 - (\[Nu]^2 - 1/4)/(\[Tau]^2))[[1]];
```

Introduce a second variable `intv[t]` in `NDSolveValue` which defines the integral of `v[t]`

```
NDSolveValue[{v'[t] + (v[t])^2 + f == 0, intv'[t] == v[t], intv[0] == 0 + 0 I, v[0] == -I*k55}, {v, intv} , {t, 0, 150}]
```

[image]

`NDSolve` claims reduced simulation range `{t,0,149}`

Check result

```
Plot[ReIm[intV[t]], {t, 0, 139}, PlotRange -> Automatic,Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Good result, however I am getting `NDSolve::ndode: The equations <<1>> are not differential equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {intv}.` when running `solv = NDSolve[{v'[t] + (v[t])^2 + f == 0, intv'[t] == v[t], 
   intv[0] == 1/Sqrt[2*k55], v[0] == -I*k55}, {v, intv}, {t, 0, 150}]`.

Comment: Change ic to `intv[0] == 1/Sqrt[2*k55]+0 I`. Now `NDSolve`assumes complex intv.

Comment: What I did is to quit the kernel and start again, it worked surprisingly. I do not know why there is an error after running a second time the code.

Comment: Now I am facing some trouble when running the code you provided, `NDSolveValue[{v'[t] + (v[t])^2 + f == 0, intv'[t] == v[t], intv[0] == 0 + 0 I, v[0] == -I*k55}, {v, intv} , {t, 0, 150}]`.  It says `NDSolveValue::ndfdmc: Computed derivatives do not have dimensionality consistent with the initial conditions.`

Comment: Did  you modify the definitions `k55, f` ?

Comment: Yeah, just as you mentioned with the `[[1]]`

Comment: I found a worse problem, running `solv = NDSolve[{v'[t] + (v[t])^2 + f == 0, v[0] == -I*k55}, {v}, {t, 0, 150}]` is supposed to give a function `v[t]` solution of the differential equation `v'[t]+(v[t])^2+f==0`. However, while substituting the solution, it does not fit, and it even highly oscilates in orders of `10^5`.

Comment: Usually plotting the ode with the numerical solution doesn't give `0`