# Numerically solving Helmholtz equation in 2D for arbitrary shapes

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I would like to solve the Helmholtz equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions in two dimensions for an arbitrary shape (for a qualitative comparison of the eigenstates to periodic orbits in the corresponding [billiard systems](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Billiards.html)):

$\Omega =$ some boundary e.g. a circle, a regular polygon etc.

$
\nabla^2 u(x,y) + k^2u(x,y) =0 \quad x,y \in \Omega \\
u(x,y) = 0 \quad x,y \in \partial\Omega
$

There seems already to be a solution [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolvingThe2DHelmholtzPartialDifferentialEquationUsingFiniteD/); unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough with *Mathematica* to extract a minimal working example from this code and adapt it to my needs.

**Is there a way to use `NDSolve` (or `ParametricNDSolve`) to calculate the eigenvalues k and corresponding eigenstates for the problem?**

As far as I understand *Mathematica* can handle FEM and finite difference methods, which could be used to solve this kind of equations?

Comment: Look into [What's New in M10](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/) for a start.

Comment: If you're looking for insights about the correspondence between the billiard-ball problem and the Helholtz and Schrödinger equations, a great place to go is David Tannor's [Introduction to Quantum Mechanics: a Time-Dependent Perspective](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Introduction_to_Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=t7m08j3Wi9YC).

Comment: Version 11 has both symbolic and numeric eigensolvers, [here is an overview](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/differential-eigensystems/?product=mathematica)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I've encapsulated the code of the mysterious user21 into a `helmholzSolve` command.  The code is at the end of this post. It adds very little to user21's code but it does allow us to examine multiple examples quite easily, though it has certainly not been tested extensively and could be improved quite a lot I'm sure.  It should be called as follows:

```
{ev,if,mesh} = helmholzSolve[g_Graphics, n_Integer, opts:OptionsPattern[]];
```

In this code, `g` can be a `Graphics` object, an `ImplicitRegion`, or a `ParametricRegion` defining the region in question, `n` is an integer determining the number of eigenvalues that will be computed, and `opts` is a list of options to be passed to the discretization functions.  It returns `ev` a list of the computed eigenvalues, `if` a list of corresponding eigenfunctions represented as `InterpolatingFunction`s and the `mesh` for plotting purposes.  Using this, we can compute the eigenfunctions of the unit disk is as easy as follows:

```
{ev, if, mesh} = helmholzSolve[Disk[], 6];
ev
(* Out: {6.80538, 15.7385, 15.7385, 27.477, 27.477, 31.5901} *)
```

We can visualize the eigenfunctions as follows:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[ContourPlot[if[[k]][x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50], {k, 1, 6}], 3]]
```

[image]

Here's a semi-interesting region:

```
n = 20;
vertices = Table[(1 + (-1)^k/5) {Cos[2 Pi*k/n], Sin[2 Pi*k/n]}, {k, 1, n}];
g = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Gray, Polygon[vertices]}]
```

[image]

And the plot of an eigenfunction:

```
{ev, if, mesh} = helmholzSolve[g, 6, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.005];
Plot3D[-if[[6]][x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 20, Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.3]]
```

[image]

Here's an implicitly defined region with a hole:

```
{ev, if, mesh} = helmholzSolve[
   ImplicitRegion[1/4 < x^2 + y^2 && x^4 + y^6 <= 1, {x, y}],
  4];
ContourPlot[if[[4]][x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

Finally, here's the definition of `helmholzSolve`.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
helmholzSolve[g_, numEigenToCompute_Integer, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {u, x, y, t, pde, dirichletCondition, mesh, boundaryMesh,
   nr, state, femdata, initBCs, methodData, initCoeffs, vd, sd,
   discretePDE, discreteBCs, load, stiffness, damping, pos, nDiri,
   numEigen, res, eigenValues, eigenVectors, evIF},

  (* Discretize the region *)
  If[Head[g] === ImplicitRegion || Head[g] === ParametricRegion,
    mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeRegion[g], opts],
    mesh = ToElementMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[g], opts]
  ];
  boundaryMesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];

  (* Set up the PDE and boundary condition *)
  pde = D[u[t,x,y], t] - Laplacian[u[t,x,y], {x, y}] +  u[t,x,y] == 0;
  dirichletCondition = DirichletCondition[u[t,x,y] == 0, True];

  (* Pre-process the equations to obtain the FiniteElementData in StateData *)
  nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
  {state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{pde, dirichletCondition, 
     u[0, x, y] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}, Element[{x, y}, nr]];
  femdata = state["FiniteElementData"];
  initBCs = femdata["BoundaryConditionData"];
  methodData = femdata["FEMMethodData"];
  initCoeffs = femdata["PDECoefficientData"];

  (* Set up the solution *)
  vd = methodData["VariableData"];
  sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr, "Time" -> 0.}];

  (* Discretize the PDE and boundary conditions *)
  discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
  discreteBCs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];

  (* Extract the relevant matrices and deploy the boundary conditions *)
  load = discretePDE["LoadVector"];
  stiffness = discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
  damping = discretePDE["DampingMatrix"];
  DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness, damping}, discreteBCs];

  (* Set the number of eigenvalues ignoring the Dirichlet positions *)
  pos = discreteBCs["DirichletMatrix"]["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]];
  nDiri = Length[pos];
  numEigen = numEigenToCompute + nDiri;

  (* Solve the eigensystem *)
  res = Eigensystem[{stiffness, damping}, -numEigen];
  res = Reverse /@ res;
  eigenValues = res[[1, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
  eigenVectors = res[[2, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
  evIF = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, #] & /@ eigenVectors ;

  (* Return the relevant information *)
  {eigenValues, evIF, mesh}
]
```

Comment: It is also possible to solve unconstrained eigenvalue problems: In that case no `DirichletCondition` are applied.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats exactly what I needed.Just a minor thing:
Adding $Head[g] === RegionIntersection$ and $Head[g] === RegionUnion$ to the If condition allows for an easy creation of the boundary.
Just as a comment: For large k values the FEM method is known to have problems due to the so called pollution effect. One has to carefully select the mesh if quantitative correct results are desired.

Answer (score 90):

**Update:**

Since long the system function [NDEigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) does exactly what was requested. The original post serves as guideline of how the implementation works in principal.

**Original Post:**

OK, there is good news and there is bad news. In the current version 10 there is no way to do this directly. That's the bad news. The good news is that finite element framework used within `NDSolve` is exposed and [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html); for maximum "hackability" convenience.

Let's start with a region that @MarkMcClure would consider interesting.

We load our favorite package:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(*Compute an eigenfunction of a Helmholzian on the Koch \
Snowflake*)(*lev controls the level of the approximation.*)
lev = 3;
boundaryLev = lev + 1;
KochStep[{p1_, p2_}] := 
  With[{q1 = p1 + (p2 - p1)/3, 
    q2 = (p1 + (p2 - p1)/3) + RotationMatrix[-Pi/3].(p2 - p1)/3, 
    q3 = p1 + 2 (p2 - p1)/3}, {p1, q1, q2, q3, p2}];
KochStep[pp : {{_, _} ..}] := 
  Join[Partition[Flatten[Most /@ (KochStep /@ Partition[pp, 2, 1])], 
    2], {pp[[-1]]}];
KochVertices = 
  Nest[KochStep, 
   N@{{3 Sqrt[3]/4, 3/4}, {-3 Sqrt[3]/4, 
      3/4}, {0, -3/2}, {3 Sqrt[3]/4, 3/4}}, boundaryLev];
Graphics[Point[KochVertices]]
```

[image]

We then first generate a boundary mesh and then the full mesh:

```
boundaryMesh = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> KochVertices, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
      Partition[Range[Length[KochVertices]], 2, 1, {1, 1}]]}];

boundaryMesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[boundaryMesh, "MeshOrder" -> 1, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.005];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Now for the real stuff. An eigen value problem can be considered as a transient problem.

```
k = 1/10;
pde = D[u[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + k^2 u[t, x, y] == 0;
Γ = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True];
```

We use `NDSolve` as a pre-processor:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{pde, Γ, u[0, x, y] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} ∈ nr];
```

Extract the finite element data:

```
femdata = state["FiniteElementData"]

initBCs = femdata["BoundaryConditionData"];
methodData = femdata["FEMMethodData"];
initCoeffs = femdata["PDECoefficientData"];
```

Set up the solution and variable data:

```
vd = methodData["VariableData"];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr, "Time" -> 0.}];
```

Discretize the PDE and the boundary conditions:

```
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
discreteBCs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];
```

Extract the system matrices:

```
load = discretePDE["LoadVector"];
stiffness = discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
damping = discretePDE["DampingMatrix"];
```

Deploy the boundary conditions:

```
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness, damping}, discreteBCs]
```

Set the number of X smallest eigen values we would like to compute but ignore the Dirichlet positions.

```
nDiri = First[Dimensions[discreteBCs["DirichletMatrix"]]];

numEigenToCompute = 5;
numEigen = numEigenToCompute + nDiri;
```

Solve the eigen system:

```
res = Eigensystem[{stiffness, damping}, -numEigen];
res = Reverse /@ res;
eigenValues = res[[1, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
eigenVectors = res[[2, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
(*res=Null;*)
```

Creating the interpolating functions:

```
evIF = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, #] & /@ eigenVectors;
```

Plotting the 5th eigen mode

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[evIF[[5]][x, y]], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None, ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 1.5}, 
 Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/4}, ImageSize -> 612, 
 Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Voilà.

If you are interested in eigenmode analysis for structural mechanics, have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57391/18437)

Comment: I'm ridiculously excited!

Comment: Excellent. That is all.

Comment: If you set `numEigenToCompute=6` and then plot `-efIF[[6]]`, you essentially get the [MATLink Logo](http://matlink.org/), though that was computed using a finite difference technique applied to a regular triangular grid.

Comment: Hopefully, a future version will include some functionality do compute this directly and make this monkey business irrelevant. But with the low level FEM functions one can do a lot of stuff regardless if the functionality is already implemented or not.

Comment: It looks like you're headed for a Populist badge.  Preemptive congratulations. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not if I delete my answer! I am rather embarrassed to have the accept. :)

Comment: @Mark And rob user21 of a rare Gold badge?  Shame on you. ;-p

Comment: Extraordinary work.  Beautiful.

Comment: "An eigen value problem can be considered as a transient problem. " Er… Can you elaborate a little this point? This isn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: @xzczd, it is important to realize that the discretized versions of `t*D[u[t,x],t]` and `r*u[t,x]` are the same for `t==r`. Try it out. Use `DiscretizePDE` where you have InitializezPDECoefficients` with the "DampingCoefficients" -> {{1}} and the "ReactionCoefficients"->{{1}} and then check that the damping system matrix is the same as the stiffness system matrix. This approach has many advantages. - You can easily do eigensystems of wave equations or you can have  a reaction term in the PDE that is not lambda. But all in all this is an implementation detail.

Comment: @user21 I'm not sure whether I understand the logic. The idea seems to be introducing the auxiliary equation:$\partial_t u=(-E-a)u$, then $-\nabla^2 u= E u \Rightarrow \partial_t u-\nabla^2u+au=0$, so the eigenvalue equation is a subset of the transient equation. If the logic were true, the magic number `k=1/10`in your post could, in principle, be arbitrary? It surprises me that the last equation is easier to solve in `NDSolve` framework. Also I wonder weather `NDEigensystem` is a implementation of this idea?

Comment: @luyuwuli, the idea is based on the fact that the FEM discretization of D[u,t] is the same as u (without temporal derivative). In other words the reaction term is the same as the transient term D[u,t] or any higher order transient term. You can check this yourself: Use `InitializePDECoefficients` once with "DampingCoefficient"->{{1}} (or "MassCoefficient"->{{1}}) and compare that to one setup with "ReactionCoefficient"->{{1}} the damping (mass) matrix is then the same as the stiffness matrix. And, yes, `NDEigensystem` is implemented like that.

Comment: @luyuwuli, note that I am not *solving* D[u,t]=\nabla a. I am just using that to construct the separated damping and stiffness system matrices. The solver use `Eigensystem` to find the (generalized) eigen system of the system matrices.

Answer (score 27):

## As of v10.3, this is now possible

using the built-in commands [**`DEigensystem`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DEigensystem.html) and [**`NDEigensystem`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) functions. These work pretty much as you hope they would, along the lines of

> `DEigensystem[ℒ[u[x, y, …]], u, {x, y, …} ∈ Ω, n]`
> gives the n smallest magnitude eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for the linear differential operator ℒ over the region Ω.

Hat-tip to Mark McClure for [pointing these out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227707/can-you-hear-the-shape-of-a-drum-by-choosing-where-to-drum-it/230197?noredirect=1#comment576896_230197) to me.

As a simple illustration,

```
{eigenvalues[region], eigenfunctions[region]}=NDEigensystem[
   {-Laplacian[u[x,y], {x,y}],
   DirichletCondition[u[x,y]==0, True]}
   , u[x,y]
   , {x,y} ∈ region
   , 6
  ];
Grid[Partition[Table[
 Show[{
   ContourPlot[
    eigenfunctions[region][[j]]
    , {x,y} ∈ region
    , Frame -> None, PlotPoints -> 60, PlotRange -> Full
    , PlotLabel -> eigenvalues[region][[j]]
   ],
   RegionPlot[region, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
  }]
 ,{j, 1, Length[eigenvalues[region]]}], 3]]
```

produces with, for example, a disk,

```
region = Disk[]
```

plots like

[image]

or with the star from above,

```
With[{n=20},
  region=Polygon[Table[(1+(-1)^k/5) {Cos[2 Pi*k/n],Sin[2 Pi*k/n]},{k,1,n}]]
];
```

[image]

or for the implicit region with a hole,

```
region = ImplicitRegion[1/4 < x^2 + y^2 && x^4 + y^6 <= 1, {x, y}];
```

[image]

and even for the Koch snowflake of user21, defined as

```
lev = 3;
boundaryLev = lev + 1;
KochStep[{p1_, p2_}] := 
  With[{q1 = p1 + (p2 - p1)/3, 
    q2 = (p1 + (p2 - p1)/3) + RotationMatrix[-Pi/3].(p2 - p1)/3, 
    q3 = p1 + 2 (p2 - p1)/3}, {p1, q1, q2, q3, p2}];
KochStep[pp : {{_, _} ..}] := 
  Join[Partition[Flatten[Most /@ (KochStep /@ Partition[pp, 2, 1])], 
    2], {pp[[-1]]}];
KochVertices = 
  Nest[KochStep, 
   N@{{3 Sqrt[3]/4, 3/4}, {-3 Sqrt[3]/4, 
      3/4}, {0, -3/2}, {3 Sqrt[3]/4, 3/4}}, boundaryLev];
region=Polygon[KochVertices];
```

the first nine eigenfunctions look like

[image]

or zooming in to the fourth one, using

```
Plot3D[
 Quiet[eigenfunctions[region][[4]]]
 , {x, y} ∈ region
 , PlotRange -> Full
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.25}
 , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}
 , PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

you get

[image]

This is in no way meant to underappreciate the really good work by Mark and user21, of course - just to say that you'd hope for this functionality to be built-in and, since recently, it finally is.

Comment: Do you know what methods are used in the solving of the eigenvalue problem? Are they mesh based methods?

Comment: @Beni I don't really, and indeed [the usual WRI position](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html) is rather closed to giving too many details on the implementation. That said, NDEigensystem is almost certainly riding on top of the same Finite Element API that user21's code uses, which can be seen from the documentation of its Method option. (DEigensystem, on the other hand, is quite likely a very different beast, and like most of Mathematica's symbolic integration is probably very different to human methods of solution.)

Comment: @BeniBogosel, I only saw this comment now. `NDEigensystem` basically follows what was described in the post above. So, yes, it's mesh based and used the finite element method for discretization.