# Test a wooden board's vibration mode

Tags: numerical-integration, simulation, finite-element-method

Here is a wooden board, with dimensions shown on the picture below. How we
can use Mathematica's newly build-in finite element analysis features to show the different
modes of its vibrations. Assuming the board is made of spruce.

[image]

Comment: Once again, interesting question but you are missing the fact that you should at least try something.

Comment: Any *specific* material simulation implied by "made of spruce" is surely too involved to be answered here so I recommend removing that phrase.  Without it I think the braced panel simulation is an interesting question and *perhaps* of reasonable scope.  It would greatly help your chances of receiving an answer if you described an actual algorithm or approach that you seek help implementing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Would you also think that "please show me how to find the ground state of the 2d Kitaev model with Mathematica's linear algebra tools" is of reasonable scope? If not, why not? (in fact, mine is a much, *much* less technically involved question--unless we do include the spruce bit).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, before you close this, give me some time - I might get a Reversal if I wait a little longer....

Comment: @acl Please read this: [(1307)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1307) -- In no way do I think that anyone should feel pressured to answer a question like this, but I think that (1) It may be more motivation than many other questions; (2) it might be an opportunity for someone to share already developed code; (3) if answered well it could be of interest to a lot of people and would serve to advertise *Mathematica*'s capabilities and possibly our site.

Comment: @acl Basically I think that it is better to ignore a question like this than close it.  *If* there is interest it will manifest in time; if not it can later be closed or deleted.  (A negatively-voted question with no answers will be auto-deleted in time anyway.)

Comment: @acl Oh, and one more thing: at present the Question is not ideal which is why I am attempting to encourage the user to improve it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm not implying that anybody is getting pressured. All I am saying is that this is a question of precisely the same type as the one I posed, which presumably you'd not find good (as it is not well written, not necessarily valuable for future readers unless and not of reasonable scope, as it does not even attempt to express things in programming terms). That is, it does not satisfy 3 of the 4 criteria in the question you linked to.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Also, it's not that unreasonable to expect that the answer to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56305/16) could be modified to apply here. Does it? Does it not? Why not? We're not told.

Comment: @acl I see no problem for criterion #3; in fact that's the reason I'm giving this a chance.  #1 and #4 are surely shaky, and #2 is yet to be seen as I think is often the case.  I suspect that the existing Q&A you reference can serve as a foundation to answer this one, if someone has specific acoustical knowledge.  As stated I think the question does need to be improved.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, as you can see I did not vote for it to be closed. Maybe you're right.

Comment: At the least the OP could provide (links to) the equations describing the vibration, or do we have to do the whole (home)work ourselves?

Comment: Have a look at the example "Solve a Wave Equation in 2D" [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-a-wave-equation-in-2d.html). It shows how you can solve the 2D wave equation over a non-trivial region. For instance, if I understand your diagram correctly, your region would be `RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {40, 76}], RegionUnion[Rectangle[{40/2 - 5/2, 76/2 - 68/2}, {40/2 + 5/2, 76/2 + 68/2}], Rectangle[{40/2 - 36/2, 76/2 - 5/2}, {40/2 + 36/2, 76/2 + 5/2}]]]`. You would need to define an initial condition to start off the 2D wave solution.

Answer (score 69):

The only reason I am attempting to answer this is to perhaps get a Reversal badge. There you go...

We will go slowly and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437) answer is the basis for what comes next. Let's start with two dimensions. You'll see why.

We create a rectangular region:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, "MeshOrder" -> 1, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.005];
```

We use the plane stress equations of a material sheet. For every material you need to set the Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio.

```
planeStress = {Inactive[
       Div][{{0, -((Y*ν)/(1 - ν^2))}, {-(Y*(1 - ν))/(2*(1 \
- ν^2)), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
     Inactive[
       Div][{{-(Y/(1 - ν^2)), 
         0}, {0, -(Y*(1 - ν))/(2*(1 - ν^2))}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}], 
    Inactive[
       Div][{{0, -(Y*(1 - ν))/(2*(1 - ν^2))}, {-((Y*ν)/(1 \
- ν^2)), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
     Inactive[
       Div][{{-(Y*(1 - ν))/(2*(1 - ν^2)), 
         0}, {0, -(Y/(1 - ν^2))}}.Inactive[Grad][
        v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]} /. {Y -> 10^3, ν -> 33/100};
```

Make a coupled, time dependent PDE and constrain the region to not move at the left boundary.

```
pde2D = D[{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}, t] + planeStress == {0, 0};
(* held fixed at left *)
bcs = DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, x==0];
```

What follows next, is pretty much the same from the other post.

```
(*We use NDSolve as a pre-processor:*)
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{pde2D, bcs, u[0, x, y] == 0, 
    v[0, x, y] == 0}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}}];

(*Extract the finite element data:*)
femdata = state["FiniteElementData"];

initBCs = femdata["BoundaryConditionData"];
methodData = femdata["FEMMethodData"];
initCoeffs = femdata["PDECoefficientData"];

(*Set up the solution and variable data:*)
vd = methodData["VariableData"];
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr, "Time" -> 0.}];

(*Discretize the PDE and the boundary conditions:*)
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
discreteBCs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];
(*Extract the system matrices:*)
load = discretePDE["LoadVector"];
stiffness = discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
damping = discretePDE["DampingMatrix"];

(*Deploy the boundary conditions:*)
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, 
  stiffness, damping}, discreteBCs]

(*Set the number of X smallest eigen values we would like to compute \
but ignore the Dirichlet positions.*)

nDiri = If[Length[#] > 0, First[#], 0] &[
   Dimensions[discreteBCs["DirichletMatrix"]]];

numEigenToCompute = 5;
numEigen = numEigenToCompute + nDiri;
```

Now, things become hard. We solve the eigensystem.

```
(*Solve the eigen system: this is how you should do it*)
res = Eigensystem[{stiffness, damping}, -numEigen];
```

You will need patience. Play with the "Arnoldi" method and the shift. (left as an exercise). As a bad alternative you can play with

```
(* this may be a bit faster but is the dark side... *)
(*
mm=LinearSolve[damping,stiffness];
res=Eigensystem[mm,-numEigen];
*)
```

Further down I use "FEAST" as a solve.

For each eigenvalue we now have two eigenvectors. Once in the x-direction and one in the y-direction. So we post-process:

```
res = Reverse /@ res;
eigenValues = res[[1, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
eigenVectors = res[[2, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
(*res=Null;*)
inciOffs = methodData["IncidentOffsets"];
 spans = MapThread[Span, {Most[inciOffs] + 1, Rest[inciOffs]}];
 eigenVectors = 
  Transpose[
   Developer`ToPackedArray[eigenVectors[[All, #]] & /@ spans], {2, 1, 
    3}];
 eigenVectorsIF = Table[{}, {numEigenToCompute}, {Length[spans]}];
 Do[
  eigenVectorsIF[[i, j]] = 
   NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
    eigenVectors[[i, j]]] 
  , {i, numEigenToCompute}, {j, Length[spans]}];
res = {eigenValues, eigenVectorsIF};
```

And visualize the first 5 eigenvectos in the x-direction:

```
Show[NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D[res[[2, #, 1]]["Coordinates"][[1]],
     NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshDirective -> 
     Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[]]], 
   NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D[res[[2, #, 1]]], Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600] & /@ Range[numEigenToCompute];
```

Visualize the y-direction:

```
Show[NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D[res[[2, #, 2]]["Coordinates"][[1]],
     NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshDirective -> 
     Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[]]], 
   NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D[res[[2, #, 2]]], Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600] & /@ Range[numEigenToCompute];
```

And the "breathing modes" enlarged by a factor. (I just invented that name - it might mean something else)

```
fact = 5;
Show[{
    NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D[res[[2, 2, 1]]["Coordinates"][[1]], 
     NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshDirective -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[]]],
    NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshPlot3D[
     NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshInterpolation[
      res[[2, #, 1]]["Coordinates"], 
      fact*Sqrt[Total[#["ValuesOnGrid"]^2 & /@ res[[2, #]]]]]]
    }, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600] & /@ Range[numEigenToCompute]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The 3D case. Unfortunately, my local super-computer center is closed, but here is how to do it. Create a mesh and enlarge the features for now to create not too many elements.

```
base = {0, 0, 0};
h1 = 5;
h2 = 5;
w1 = 40;
l1 = 76;
cw1 = 5;
cl1 = 68;
cw2 = 36;
cl2 = 5;
offset1 = base + {(w1 - cw1)/2, (l1 - cl1)/2, 0};
offset2 = base + {(w1 - cw2)/2, (l1 - cl2)/2, 0};
offset3 = base + {(w1 - cw1)/2, (l1 - cl2)/2, 0};
ClearAll[rect]
rect[base_, w_, l_, h_] := {base + {0, 0, h}, base + {w, 0, h}, 
  base + {w, l, h}, base + {0, l, h}}
coords = ConstantArray[{0., 0., 0.}, 4 + 4 + 12 + 12];
coords[[{1, 2, 3, 4}]] = rect[base, w1, l1, 0];
coords[[{5, 6, 7, 8}]] = rect[base, w1, l1, h1];
coords[[{9, 10, 15, 16}]] = rect[offset1, cw1, cl1, h1];
coords[[{19, 12, 13, 18}]] = rect[offset2, cw2, cl2, h1];
coords[[{20, 11, 14, 17}]] = rect[offset3, cw1, cl2, h1];
coords[[20 + Range[12]]] = ({0, 0, h2} + #) & /@ 
   coords[[8 + Range[12]]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {QuadElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 
       3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8},
      {5, 6, 10, 9}, {6, 12, 11, 10}, {6, 7, 13, 12}, {7, 15, 14, 
       13}, {7, 8, 16, 15}, {8, 18, 17, 16}, {8, 5, 19, 18}, {5, 9, 
       20, 19},
      Sequence @@ ({{9, 10, 11, 20}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {14, 15, 16, 
           17}, {17, 18, 19, 20}, {20, 11, 14, 17}} + 12),
      Sequence @@ (Partition[Join[Range[9, 20]], 2, 1, 
          1] /. {i1_, i2_} :> {i1, i2, i2 + 12, i1 + 12})
      }]}]
```

If you want to visualize the boundary structure:

```
Show[
 bmesh["Wireframe"],
 bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]
 ];
```

Create the mesh:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 10];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Here is the PDE stress operator in 3D:

```
stressOperator[
  Y_, ν_] := {Inactive[
     Div][{{0, 0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}, {0, 0, 
       0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
      w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 
       0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 
       0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0}, {0, 
       0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
      u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
       0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 
              2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
       0}}.Inactive[Grad][w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
       0}, {-((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
       0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 
       0}, {0, -((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0}, {0,
        0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
       0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}, {0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 
              2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{0, 0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}, {0, 0, 
       0}, {-((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 0}}.Inactive[
       Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0}, {0,
        0, -((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}}.Inactive[
       Grad][w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]}
```

And the 3D PDE. no boundary conditions, it seems an unconstraint analysis is wanted.

```
(* choose your Y and ν -- no idea what the values for spruce are - 
   is it wet, dry, old, ...? *)
pde3D = D[{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t] + 
    stressOperator[100, 1/3] == {0, 0, 0};
(* unconstraint? Yes! *)
bcs = Sequence[];
```

If you want a constraint analysis then you'd have to set `DirichletCondition` on the boundary (`bcs = DirichletCondition[{u[x,y,z]==0,v[x,y,z]==0,w[x,y,z]==0},True]`)

Now, we use

```
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{pde3D, bcs, u[0, x, y, z] == 0, 
    v[0, x, y, z] == 0, w[0, x, y, z] == 0}, {u, v, w}, {t, 0, 
    1}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}}];
```

for pre-processing. There may be a waring about no DirichletCondition or no NeumannValue; this is save to ignore in this case.

And now the same as above - it will take a long time.... I did not want to wait. (Also I did not want to think about how to visualize this in 3D... that's for you...)

When you do this do not forget that the result need to be sorted and post processed as in the 2D example above. i.e.

```
res = Reverse /@ res;
eigenValues = res[[1, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
eigenVectors = res[[2, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];
```

**Update:**

The `Eigensystem` solution above takes about 450 seconds on my machine. You can use

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Eigensystem[{stiffness, damping}, -numEigen, 
    Method -> {"FEAST", "Tolerance" -> 10^-6}];]
```

to get it down to 45 seconds. Which is a bit better.

Here are the deformations for the eigenmodes 7 to 10 - the first 6 are zero. (I must admit that that I am not sure if that makes sense)

```
res[[1]]
{0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.011403583383327644`, \
0.01526089137692353`, 0.05661022352859022`, 0.07266104128273859`}
```

And the visualizations:

```
MeshRegion[
   ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, res[[2, #]], 
    "ScalingFactor" -> 100]] & /@ Range[7, numEigenToCompute]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When you run the 3D exmaple, please adjust the `numEigenToCompute` to be appropriate.

Anything else?

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Öskå, the problem with `Eigensystem` as it is used here is that this calls a direct solver for the generalized eigenvalue problem. I need to find a better solution for that. You do not by any change have access to Abaqus/Ansys or the like and could try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16455/discussion-between-user21-and-oska).

Comment: Congratulations on the Reversal badge -- even if you did game it. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, ;-) yea I did :-P - I am such a scoundrel. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, but on a more serious note, I don't think the SE/SO voting works too well, it is just not objective. Compare the up/down votes [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57366/18437) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56305/18437); just having an equation does not justify such a difference, I think.

Comment: I agree; it's quite capricious, as I [once lamented.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/348/121)  If you find any question or answer that seem to be egregiously overlooked and you feel that your one vote simply isn't enough let me know; I might just put a Bounty on it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I hope we are not miss understanding each other. I am claiming that upvotes for questions depend on the timeliness and quality of the answer given. Which, I think, is nonsense. A question can not be 'good' or 'bad' just because there is a 'good' or 'bad' answer to it. I think there are many more issues with this voting thing. What you mention is certainly also a valid observation.

Comment: I either don't understand or disagree with your assertion, at least least for the examples given.  *This* is a good answer yet the question has a negative score.  The other Q&A also has good answers and it has a very positive score.  While I have seen a question suddenly rise in popularity after a good answer is posted I think that is only natural given the additional interest (and views) that the answer can create; this is especially true for a question that is hard to understand but which when illuminated is interesting.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think that's the point I am trying to make. The perceived question quality depends on other influences - it's not only the questions as such that got voted upon. And since those outside influences are not quantifiable that leads me to believe that the votes are not a terribly good classification. I don't want to get overly philosophical here. While it was good that the 'forum' situation got a new paint (with SE/SO), I hope for a further evolution of 'forum' technology.

Comment: If you have some good ideas I would like to hear them.  http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/ is the place for that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, unfortunately, I don't. It's more of an observation.

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating the 3D example. When postprocessing the Eigensystem solution, I get errors "ElementMeshInterpolation::vvalues: -- Message text not found -- (160)". Subsequently I can't visualize the deformed mesh.

Comment: @shrx, I added some code for the 3D problem. Does that help?

Answer (score 9):

This is not another answer but an attempt to repeat the calculations [in the other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57391/12558) in version 11. There are problems at the end for which I need help (edit: now sorted and corrected below). Note that there is a more direct method using NDEigensystem which is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125713/12558). There are issues with the eigen solver which may take a long time; this is discussed above and in the referenced question.

I am also writing this answer as it provides a workflow for solving a vibration eigenvalue problem where details need to be extracted. I make some comments that may help those used to doing vibration calculations.

Set up the stress operator for a general structural, time dependent systems. (Note that you can't just type in the textbook equations because there needs to be appropriate `Inactive` commands).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]


ClearAll[stressOperator, u, v, w, t, x, y, z]; 
stressOperator[
  Y_, ν_] := {Inactive[
     Div][{{0, 0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}, {0, 0, 
       0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
      w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 
       0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 
       0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0}, {0, 
       0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
      u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
       0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 
              2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
       0}}.Inactive[Grad][w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
       0}, {-((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
       0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 
       0}, {0, -((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0}, {0,
        0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
       0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}, {0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 
              2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
      v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{0, 0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}, {0, 0, 
       0}, {-((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 0}}.Inactive[
       Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0}, {0,
        0, -((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}}.Inactive[
       Grad][w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]}
```

Now make the geometry

```
 base = {0, 0, 0};
    h1 = 5;
    h2 = 5;
    w1 = 40;
    l1 = 76;
    cw1 = 5;
    cl1 = 68;
    cw2 = 36;
    cl2 = 5;
    offset1 = base + {(w1 - cw1)/2, (l1 - cl1)/2, 0};
    offset2 = base + {(w1 - cw2)/2, (l1 - cl2)/2, 0};
    offset3 = base + {(w1 - cw1)/2, (l1 - cl2)/2, 0};
    ClearAll[rect]
    rect[base_, w_, l_, h_] := {base + {0, 0, h}, base + {w, 0, h}, 
      base + {w, l, h}, base + {0, l, h}}
    coords = ConstantArray[{0., 0., 0.}, 4 + 4 + 12 + 12];
    coords[[{1, 2, 3, 4}]] = rect[base, w1, l1, 0];
    coords[[{5, 6, 7, 8}]] = rect[base, w1, l1, h1];
    coords[[{9, 10, 15, 16}]] = rect[offset1, cw1, cl1, h1];
    coords[[{19, 12, 13, 18}]] = rect[offset2, cw2, cl2, h1];
    coords[[{20, 11, 14, 17}]] = rect[offset3, cw1, cl2, h1];
    coords[[20 + Range[12]]] = ({0, 0, h2} + #) & /@ 
       coords[[8 + Range[12]]];
    bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
       "BoundaryElements" -> {QuadElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2,
             3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}, {5, 6, 10, 9}, {6, 12, 
            11, 10}, {6, 7, 13, 12}, {7, 15, 14, 13}, {7, 8, 16, 15}, {8, 
            18, 17, 16}, {8, 5, 19, 18}, {5, 9, 20, 19}, 
           Sequence @@ ({{9, 10, 11, 20}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {14, 15, 16, 
                17}, {17, 18, 19, 20}, {20, 11, 14, 17}} + 12), 
           Sequence @@ (Partition[Join[Range[9, 20]], 2, 1, 
               1] /. {i1_, i2_} :> {i1, i2, i2 + 12, i1 + 12})}]}];
```

Show the geometry

```
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"], 
 bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MeshOrder" -> 1, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 10];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Set up the pde and give values for modulus of elasticity and Poisson ratio. Those users familiar to vibration may be surprised that the derivative with respect to time is only first order and not second (Newton's law is second). This is because the equations are converted to first order within the code and we are just trying to get the matrices. For this reason what is normally called the mass matrix is called the damping matrix here.

```
Y = 100;
ν = 1/3;
pde3D = D[{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t] + 
    stressOperator[Y, ν] == {0, 0, 0};
```

Define the boundary conditions

```
bcs = Sequence[];
```

The equations are now processed.

```
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{pde3D, bcs, u[0, x, y, z] == 0, 
    v[0, x, y, z] == 0, w[0, x, y, z] == 0}, {u, v, w}, {t, 0, 
    1}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}}];
```

The finite element data are now extracted.

```
femdata = state["FiniteElementData"];
initBCs = femdata["BoundaryConditionData"];
methodData = femdata["FEMMethodData"];
initCoeffs = femdata["PDECoefficientData"];
```

The solution and variable data are extracted

```
vd = methodData["VariableData"];
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr, "Time" -> 0.}];
```

The PDE and boundary conditions are discretized

```
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
discreteBCs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];
```

The system matrices can now be extracted

```
load = discretePDE["LoadVector"];
stiffness = discretePDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
damping = discretePDE["DampingMatrix"];
```

The system matrices must now be modified to account for the boundary conditions. This is done "in place" so there are no new matrices

```
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness, damping}, discreteBCs];
```

Now we can calculate the eigen system. I look for the smallest 10 frequencies (this is the -10). They are given in order of largest to smallest so they need to be reversed to get them from small to large. These are actually the frequencies squared because of the formulation as a standard eigenvalue problem. Take the square root to get the frequencies and divide by 2 Pi to get them in Hz.

```
AbsoluteTiming[res = Eigensystem[{stiffness, damping}, -10,
    Method -> {"FEAST", "Tolerance" -> 10^-6}];]
```

This takes about 25 seconds on my machine. Here are the results

```
TableForm[Reverse@res[[1]], TableHeadings -> {Automatic, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These agree with the original post so all is good. (This is edited from my original post, see comments, because I forgot to revers.) The first six are zero, as they should be, because there are no constraints so there are six modes of rigid body vibration at zero frequency.

Comment: Have you maybe overlooked the reversing of the result (as in the 2D case?) like so: `res = Reverse /@ res; eigenValues = res[[1, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]]; eigenVectors = res[[2, nDiri + 1 ;; Abs[numEigen]]];` I have added a note to that respect in the post.

Comment: You are, of course, correct and I had missed the Reverse. I have updated my answer. Thanks once again for your help.