# How to set the boundary fixed and apply the Young's modulus in Mathematica's FEM?

Tags: simulation, finite-element-method

Provided the [drawing .stl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9yylub9m86udpf/Test-boardOutPut.zip) is given, and the [Young's modulus is know](http://www.wood-database.com/lumber-identification/softwoods/white-spruce/), how to start a FEM vibration mode test in Mathematica? The boundary is required to be fixed and the interested focus is on the different responses over various Young's modulus.

[image]

Comment: While the topic is interesting, I would suggest that you start with simpler example (e.g. a simple plate or even a beam) to see how that works out, and ratchet up the complexity later on.

Comment: I have updated the answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57391/18437) to mention fixed (constraint) boundaries.