# digits of NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I am solving PDE by means of `NDSolve` and I am interested in a highly accurate value for the solution at a certain point. For some reason, the solution obtained by using `NDSolveValue` evaluates only to 6 digits (even if increasing `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`!).

You can find four very simple examples describing the issue below...

Particularly, I noticed the following behaviour: when solving an ODE by using `DirichletCondition`, it causes the following:

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x], {x, 2}] == 2 , u[0] == 0, u[1] == 1},     
   u, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60, PrecisionGoal -> 30, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 30];
N[sol1[1/3], 20]

sol2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x], {x, 2}] == 2 , 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 1]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 60, PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 30];
N[sol2[1/3], 20]
```

which returns as a result:

```
0.11111111111111111111
0.111111
```

While for a PDE, this does not make any difference, obtaining more than 6 digits does not seem possible ??:

```
sol4 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] - 
      2 u[x, y] == 0, u[0, y] == 0, u[x, 1] == 1}, 
   u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 30];
N[sol4[1, 0], 20]

sol3 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] - 
      2 u[x, y] == 0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 1]}, 
   u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 30];
N[sol3[1, 0], 20]
```

which returns:

```
0.297163
0.297163
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Yep, it's not possible. Mathematica's numerical methods are not designed to give 30 digits of precision. You can investigate small effects my including distorsions and solving linearized equation for them though.

Comment: Interesting observation.  FYI to view the full machine precision result do `sol4[1, 0] // FullForm` Also be aware the result of `NDSolve` is an interpolation function, so whatever result you get suffers a further loss of precision if you seek a value that doesnt happen to be a numerical grid point.

Comment: FWIW I get the same 60 digit precision result for cases 1 and 2..  It is just the PDE that runs only machine precision.

Comment: @george2079 : Do I understand you correctly, you obtain a 60 digit precision result of the function sol2[1/3] defined above ? If yes, could you please post the line of code?

Comment: I get the same `0.11111111111111111111` for both 1 and 2 using your exact code. `sol2[1/3]//Precision` shows `59.xxx....`  (version 10.1) You should specify your version.

Comment: I use version 11.1.1.0 and it returns `59.011` for `sol1[1/3]//Precision` but `MachinePrecision` for `sol2[1/2]//Precision`. So it could be that in the newer version, the use of `DirichletCondition` for an ODE will indeed invoke the FEM solver.

Answer (score 3):

FEM is restricted to machine precision (see, e.g., [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148252/gaining-precision-accuracy-with-ndeigenvalues/148273#148273)). It is automatically invoked when you use `DirichletCondition`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This answer seems to explain it... Except that george2079 says he gets up to 60 digits for sol2?

Comment: @AnSa please see: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AnSa george2079 also says "the PDE...runs only machine precision," which seems contradictory. You could reply to his comment and ask for clarification.

Comment: the first two cases are ODE's and evidently `NDSolve` respects the `WorkingPrecision` option there. The second two cases are PDE's and the calculation appears to use `MachinePrecision` regardless of the option.