# Solution to eigenvalue BVP using NDEigensystem to high precision

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to solve linear (non-self-adjoint) boundary-value problems to as high precision as possible (optimally 1e-15). For example, the below code solves for the first 5 eigenvalues of the harmonic oscillator,

$$
-u'' + V(x) u = Eu
$$

where $V(x) = x^2$ which should be solved subject to $u \to 0$ as $|x| \to \pm\infty$. It then outputs the error compared to the exact values of

$$E_n = (2n + 1), \quad n = 0, 1, \ldots
$$

```
xmax = 100;
numeigs = 5;
maxcell = 0.01;
V[x_] := x^2
Leq = -u''[x] + V[x]*u[x];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[Leq, u[x], {x, -xmax, xmax}, numeigs, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> maxcell}}}}];
vals - Table[(2*n + 1), {n, 0, numeigs - 1}]
```

with errors:

```
{2.64357*10^-11, 1.82258*10^-10, 6.51789*10^-10, 1.64085*10^-9, 
 3.36012*10^-9}
```

There are two key parameters: the `xmax` condition should tend to infinity and the `maxcell` should tend to zero. I've tried raising and lowering both but I can't seem to get better than 1e-10 at the first eigenvalue.

I've also tried adding something like this:

```
arnoldcond := 
  "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> Infinity, 
    Tolerance -> 10^(-20)};
```

but it doesn't seem to help much and to be honest I have no idea what that "Tolerance" actually does.

Additional reference
[1] [Gaining precision/accuracy with NDEigenvalues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148252/gaining-precision-accuracy-with-ndeigenvalues?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution using `NEigensystem`, but I have a package for numerically calculating solutions of eigenvalue problems using the Evans function via the method of compound matrices, which is [hosted on github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). See my [answers to other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod) or the github for some more details.

First we install the package (only need to do this the first time):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Then we first need to turn the ODEs into a matrix form $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, using my function `ToMatrixSystem`.

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]
sys = ToMatrixSystem[-u''[x] + V[x] u[x] == e u[x], {u[-L] == 0, 
    u[L] == 0}, {u}, {x, -L, L}, e] /. V -> Function[{x}, x^2]
```

Now the function `Evans` will calculate the Evans function (also known as the Miss-Distance function) for any given value of $\lambda$; this is an analytic function whose roots coincide with eigenvalues of the original equation.

```
Plot[Evans[e, sys /. L -> 5], {e, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Now `FindRoot` will find roots, and you can up the precision as required:

```
(3 - e) /. 
  FindRoot[Evans[e, sys /. L -> 10, NormalizationConstants -> 0, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50], {e, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] // Quiet
(* -1.477961860221512919729879633184*10^-19 *)
```

As this system is even, you can find even modes with only one infinite endpoint:

```
sys2 = ToMatrixSystem[-u''[x] + V[x] u[x] == e u[x], {u'[0] == 0, 
    u[L] == 0}, {u}, {x, 0, L}, e] /. V -> Function[{x}, x^2]
```

Now the default normalisation included in `Evans` works better, but it misses the odd eigenvalues:

```
Plot[Evans[e, sys2 /. L -> 5], {e, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

```
(5 - e) /. 
  FindRoot[Evans[e, sys2 /. L -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 50], {e, 
    4.01}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] // Quiet
(* 4.73068503328772292182316234385043*10^-17 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The finite element code that `NDEigensystem` uses is available only in machine precision (in Version 12.0). So in this case, if mesh refinement does not bring further improvement, you are out of luck with the FEM.