# Solving PDE with prescribed rectangular mesh

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

**Question**: I want to solve a PDE using `NDEigensystem`. The region is a rectangle `Rectangle[{0,-70}, {20, 70}]`. How can I make a mesh that satisfies the following two conditions?

(1) The mesh is finer near $y \approx 0$.

(2) The line $y=0$ should be the boundary of the mesh.

**Motivation**: The PDE that I want to solve can be written in the following command:
First, I set the mesh as below:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, -70}, {20, 70}],  
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    Block[ {x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices]; 
     If[-10 < y < 10, area > 0.1, area > 10]]] ]
```

and then write down the PDE:

```
NDEigensystem[{{3*psi3[x, y] - 10*psi2[x, y]*Sign[y] - Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y] - 
    I*Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y], 3*psi4[x, y] - 10*psi1[x, y]*Sign[y] + Derivative[0, 1][psi1][x, y] - 
    I*Derivative[1, 0][psi1][x, y], 3*psi1[x, y] - 10*psi4[x, y]*Sign[y] - Derivative[0, 1][psi4][x, y] - 
    I*Derivative[1, 0][psi4][x, y], 3*psi2[x, y] - 10*psi3[x, y]*Sign[y] + Derivative[0, 1][psi3][x, y] - 
    I*Derivative[1, 0][psi3][x, y]}, PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi1[x, y], x == 0, 
   TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi2[x, y], x == 0, 
   TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi3[x, y], x == 0, 
   TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi4[x, y], x == 0, 
   TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], DirichletCondition[psi1[x, y] == 0, 
   0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)], DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == 0, 
   0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)], DirichletCondition[psi3[x, y] == 0, 
   0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)], DirichletCondition[psi4[x, y] == 0, 
   0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)]}, {psi1, psi2, psi3, psi4}, Element[{x, y}, mesh], 10]
```

The single important fact about the PDE is that the differential operator contains $\mathrm{sgn}(y)$, hence it is not continuous at $y=0$. This is why I want the mesh boundary to include $y=0$.
The mesh I created is visualized as follows:

[image]

As wanted, the mesh is finer. However, $y=0$ is not the boundary of the mesh.

The result of one solution obtained by solving the PDE is plotted as below:

[image]

In the above plot, the horizontal direction is the $x$-direction. Note that the solution is localized near $y\approx 0$. This is why I want to make the mesh finer near $y\approx 0$. I don't believe the result is the good representation of the solution, since the graph looks jagged, which I don't expect since the differential operator has a translation symmetry in $x$-direction.

Comment: Line `y=0` is not shown in the mesh.  What boundary condition supposed to be on the line `y=0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your objectives with an anisotropic quad mesh that you construct manually. There are no diffusive terms in your operators, so [`NDEigensystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) will complain about the system being convection dominated. Therefore, you may want to take a closer look at your system of equations and see if there is an opportunity to add diffusive terms.

## Helper functions

The following helper functions will help construct an anisotropic Quad mesh (note that not all functions will be used).

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Meshes*)
pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] :=(*Quiet@*)
 Abs@FindRoot[
    firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 0.00000001, 
     100000000/fElm}, Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l];
leftSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm0[len, n, fElm]
rightSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Module[{seg}, seg = leftSegmentGrowth[len, n, fElm];
  flipSegment[seg]]
reflectRight[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]
```

## Construct anisotropic Quad mesh

The following workflow will create a symmetric graded mesh about $y=0$ and a uniform mesh in the x-direction.

```
ht = 140;
len = 20;
ny = 100;
nx = 100;
Print["Mesh along the X-direction"]
rh = pointsToMesh@Subdivide[0, len, nx]
Print["Mesh along the Y-direction"]
rv = pointsToMesh@reflectLeft@leftSegmentGrowth[ht/2, ny/2, ht/2/ny/10]
(*Create 2D mesh with RegionProduct*)
rp = RegionProduct[rh, rv];
(* Build mesh based on region product *)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 2];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[inc]}];
Print["Mesh zoomed in around y=0"]
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image: Mesh]

This mesh is refined and has a line about $y=0$.

## Solve and plot solution

```
(*Solve and plot*)
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{{3*psi3[x, y] - 10*psi2[x, y]*Sign[y] - 
      Derivative[0, 1][psi2][x, y] - I*Derivative[1, 0][psi2][x, y], 
     3*psi4[x, y] - 10*psi1[x, y]*Sign[y] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][psi1][x, y] - I*Derivative[1, 0][psi1][x, y], 
     3*psi1[x, y] - 10*psi4[x, y]*Sign[y] - 
      Derivative[0, 1][psi4][x, y] - I*Derivative[1, 0][psi4][x, y], 
     3*psi2[x, y] - 10*psi3[x, y]*Sign[y] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][psi3][x, y] - I*Derivative[1, 0][psi3][x, y]}, 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi1[x, y], x == 0, 
     TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi2[x, y], x == 0, 
     TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi3[x, y], x == 0, 
     TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[psi4[x, y], x == 0, 
     TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 20}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]], 
    DirichletCondition[psi1[x, y] == 0, 
     0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)], 
    DirichletCondition[psi2[x, y] == 0, 
     0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)], 
    DirichletCondition[psi3[x, y] == 0, 
     0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)], 
    DirichletCondition[psi4[x, y] == 0, 
     0 < x < 20 && (y == 70 || y == -70)]}, {psi1, psi2, psi3, psi4}, 
   Element[{x, y}, mesh], 10];
Table[Plot3D[
  funs[[i, 1]][x, y] Conjugate[funs[[i, 1]][x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] 
   mesh, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Chop@vals[[i]], Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image: Solution]

The solution no longer is jagged in the X-direction. However, there are many oscillations in the Y-direction.  You may need to consider diffusive terms to dampen these oscillations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Your answer does answer my question, but it is strange that the solution is not localized near $y\approx 0$. There is a good physical reason that the solution should be localized near $y\approx 0$. I may suspect that this is due to the "convection dominated PDE". How is the result reliable?

Comment: @eigenvalue The result may not be reliable. There is a good chance, but not necessarily, that a convection-dominated problem is numerically unstable. I found a question regarding the semi-classical Pauli operator here [148252](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148252/61809) that seems to have some similarity to yours, but it has a diffusive term. If there is an opportunity to add this diffusive term to your operator, it could stabilize the results. Alternatively, you could investigate adding [artificial diffusion](https://wolfram.com/xid/0b5dnfudslghelkim47pg56by19uzeqm-lbrw0t).