# Mesh with Prescribed Vertices

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, mesh

Mathematica has documentation for triangulating regions bounded by curves using e.g. TriangulateMesh. This is very useful for the work that I (aspire to) do drawing pictures of complicated surfaces with integral representations. I triangulate a region, solve my problem numerically on the vertices, and then I can make a graph over the triangulated region out of triangles which will closely resemble a solution, if one exists.

But when I want to start this numerical scheme, I will want to use a value that I know as initial data. Unfortunately, Mathematica will not give me a triangulation which is guaranteed to have any specific points as vertices, which is annoying.

Can I use TriangulateMesh to incorporate a given point? For example, suppose I want to triangulate something simple, like a disk. How can I guarantee that the origin appears as a vertex?

There is a related question [here, about adding specific edges.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242154/solving-pde-with-prescribed-rectangular-mesh). I think this is more complicated than I need, since I am not (at the moment, at least) I am only concerned with adding points, and letting Mathematica draw any edges it wants.

**Update, some months later:** I am revisiting this question because I have once again encountered this problem, and this time made some progress myself, but the progress has in turn lead to more difficulties.

Suppose I have a MeshRegion called `m` consisting of vertices, edges, and faces in a planar region. This is the kind of thing naturally made by `TriangulateMesh`, for example. Here is a way to add a specific point to the region.

First, retrieve the list `vertices = Apply[Complex, MeshCoordinates[m], 1];`

Define `NewVertices=Append[vertices,NewPoint]`. Then, find the cell which contains the vertex. In my relatively simple case, I just use `Show` to see where the point is and find the cell by zooming in. Then make a new MeshRegion by writing:

`NewMesh = MeshRegion[ReIm[NewVertices],Join[MeshCells[m, 1], {Line[{453, 645}], Line[{459, 645}], Line[{505, 645}]}]]`

Numbers are chosen from my specific example but don't mean anything here. This works great, if you only want a mesh skeleton of dimension $1$. Problem is, if I try to go further and add to this code stuff like `,Join[MeshCells[m,2],{Polygon[{a,b,c}]}`, then Mathematica complains and will not do this. In fact, it even complains if I don't try to `Join` anything at all, and just try to incorporate any of the old faces. In particular, its complaint is `nonopt`, it expects options where my 2-cells are supposed to go, even though [the documentation seems to suggest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html) I can have cells in any dimension.

What is the cause of the error, and how do I fill in my skeleton? I'd like to keep using `TriangulateMesh` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I have answered my own question. The problem was a mis-reading of the documentation. To adjoin the cells, do what I do in the question, but when Joining, join them all at once.  `Join[MeshCells[m,2],{Polygon[{a,b,c}]}` belongs in the same set of braces as `Join[MeshCells[m, 1], {Line[{453, 645}]`. To be specific, the formatting of MeshRegion is NOT `MeshRegion[{List of points},{List of edges},{List of faces}, ....]`. Rather, it's `MeshRegion[{List of points},{List of all cells of any dimension}]`.

Here is the code which corrects a region. I've taken the unit disk, and seed point the origin, but you can adapt it to any region you like:

```
`In[1]:= R = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]  
SeedPoint = {0, 0};
v = Length[MeshCells[R, 0]];`
```

Next we detect which cell contains the point you want to add, and call that cell `j`

```
`For[i = 1, i <= Length[MeshCells[R, 2]], i++,
  If[TestPoint \[Element] ConvexHullRegion[{MeshCoordinates[R] 
     [[MeshCells[R, 2][[i, 1, 1]]]], 
       MeshCoordinates[R][[MeshCells[R, 2][[i, 1, 2]]]], 
       MeshCoordinates[R][[MeshCells[R, 2][[i, 1, 3]]]]}], 
       j = i;
    Print[j]
    ];
   ];`
```

This might not be optimal, but it seems that Mathematica does not recognize Polygon[{x,y,z}] as a region, it is using the addresses x,y,z in the list of vertices to know how to draw the mesh, but not thinking of it as a subset of the plane. So this code works around by using `ConvexHullRegion` and then takes the convex hull of the three points that define each triangle. Once we know which triangle it's in, we define a new `MeshRegion` consisting of the old vertices and the seed point for its list of vertices, the edges of the old triangulation, all of the old faces except the one flagged `j`, and then we add in an edge from `SeedPoint` to each of the vertices of `j` and a face consisting of `SeedPoint` and two out of the three vertices of `j`. This is done in the following block:

```
`a = MeshCells[R, 2][[j, 1]][[1]];
 b = MeshCells[R, 2][[j, 1]][[2]];
 c = MeshCells[R, 2][[j, 1]][[3]];
 CorrectedVertices = Append[MeshCoordinates[R], SeedPoint];
 CorrectedMesh = MeshRegion[CorrectedVertices,
   Join[
   MeshCells[R, 1],
   Complement[MeshCells[R, 2], {MeshCells[R, 2][[j]]}],
   {Line[{v + 1, a}], Line[{v + 1, b}], Line[{v + 1, c}]},
   {Polygon[{v + 1, a, b}], Polygon[{v + 1, a, c}], Polygon[{v + 1, b, c}]}
   ]
 ]`
```

This code adds only a single vertex. For a fixed finite number of additional vertices, just repeat the process with each subsequent vertex. Lastly I apologize for any issues with formatting, this is my first time submitting code to this site.

Comment: Can you, please, update this answer with working code to satisfy the requirements of your question? Then, I recommend to mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @CATrevillian I've added code which should work for any triangulated region `R` and chosen seed point.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to do this with `TriangulateMesh` but you can do this with the finite element mesher [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) (See the options for more details on `"IncludePoints"`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
includeCoord = N[{{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/2}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[], "IncludePoints" -> includeCoord];
Position[mesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ includeCoord
{{{49}}, {{50}}}
```

This will generate a second order mesh - `MeshRegion` and friends understand that but can not really do anything with that. So to generate a first order FEM mesh and convert that to `MeshRegion` you can use:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
includeCoord = N[{{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/2}}];
mesh = MeshRegion[
   ToElementMesh[Disk[], "IncludePoints" -> includeCoord, 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1]];
Position[MeshCoordinates[mesh], #] & /@ includeCoord
```

Comment: I'm returning to this question some time later. While I have no doubt this solution works, I've refined the question a bit. I'm hesitant to deviate from my plan if only because I am still pretty weak with Mathematica and am worried that by adopting a wildly different strategy. I may make things worse for myself by not understanding how the code works when other things break down the line.

Answer (score 1):

We can identify the polygon (`p`)  that is nearest the added vertex (`v`) using the function `` Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex `` and replace `p` with triangles formed by `v` and successive pairs of  vertices of `p`.

```
ClearAll[addVertex]
addVertex[mesh_, pt : {__?NumericQ}, threshold_: 10^-3] :=
 Module[{mc = Append[pt]@MeshCoordinates[mesh],
   nci = Region`Mesh`MeshNearestCellIndex[mesh]@pt},
   If[RegionDistance[RegionBoundary@MeshPrimitives[mesh, nci]]@pt < threshold,
   mesh,
   MeshRegion[mc,
    {DeleteCases[MeshCells[mesh, nci]]@MeshCells[mesh, 2],
     Polygon[Append[Length@mc]@#] & /@ Partition[First@MeshCells[mesh, nci], 2, 1, 1]}]]]
```

For the case of multiple new vertices, `Fold` the function `addVertex` over the new vertices:

```
addVertex[mesh_, pts : {{__?NumericQ} ..}] := Fold[addVertex, mesh, pts]
```

***Examples:***

```
region = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> .2, ImageSize -> 500];

newpoints = {{0, 0}, {.3, .5}};

Row[{Show[region, Graphics[{Red, PointSize @ Medium, Point@newpoints}]],
   Show[addVertex[region, newpoints], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@newpoints}], ImageSize -> 500],
   Show[HighlightMesh[addVertex[region, newpoints], 
     Style[#, EdgeForm[White], Opacity[.5], RandomColor[]] & /@ 
      Complement[Flatten@MeshCells[addVertex[region, newpoints], 2], 
        Flatten@MeshCells[region, 2]], ImageSize -> 500], 
   MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates@region, MeshCells[region, All], 
    PlotTheme -> "Lines", 
    MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black, Thick]}], 
   Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point@newpoints}]]}]
```

[image]

Use

```
SeedRandom[7]
points = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {12, 2}];
region = VoronoiMesh[points, ImageSize -> 500];
newpoints = RandomPoint[vor, 7];
```

to get

[image]

**Note:** If the new vertex `v` is *close*  to the boundary of the polygon `p` nearest `v` (that is, its distance from the boundary of `p` is less than optional third argument `threshold`), then `p` is not touched.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It seems like it's the same idea, but implemented with more finesse with Mathematica. I'm going to look this over carefully so I can learn something.

Comment: @kglr Thanks for your hint, I tried your code, but it doesn't run in v12.2, `addVertex[region, newpoints]` just returns the input. One additional question concerning the function `addVertex`: I don't understand the if-command, does it accept lists as first argument(because `pt` is a list)? Thanks

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, try if `addVertex[DiscretizeRegion@N@region, newpoints]` work. The part with  `If[..]` defines `addVertex` for the case where the second argument is a single point. For the case where the second argument is a list of points, we use `Fold`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks for your helpful assistance.