# How to mesh a cylinder with helix points?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I would like to mesh  a cylinder surface. The mesh should include given cylinderpoints which lie on a helix.

My attempt using "IncludePoints"

```
zyl = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && -Pi <= z <= Pi, {x, y, z}]
heli = ParametricRegion[{Cos[3 phi], Sin[3 phi],phi}, {{phi, -Pi, Pi}}]

Show[{Region[zyl], Region[Style[heli, {Thickness[Large], Red}]] }]
```

[image]

some points of the helix

```
heliP = Map[#[[1]] &, MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[heli], 0] ];
```

elementmesh

```
mesh = ToBoundaryMesh[zyl, "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement" , 
"MeshOrder" -> 1, "IncludePoints" -> heliP , "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1
]

Show[{mesh["Wireframe"], Graphics3D[{Red, Point[heliP]}]}]
```

[image]

Plot shows the complete triangle mesh, unfortunately the points of the helix(red) are no meshpoints!

What's wrong with my approach?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for the data structure "elementmesh"

Comment: IncludePionts is for full element meshes; more the include points can not be on the boundary.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for your comment. "Fullelement" mesh means space and element dimension must be the same?

Comment: how does the option  "MaxCellMeasure"->1  affect the outcome? @user21: the documentation says otherwise

Comment: @user21 Simplified problem: How could I mesh a rectangle with constraint all included points  of the diagonal are meshpoints (Mathematica v12.2)? Thanks!

Comment: @wvt_beginner, what in the documentation suggests this?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I'm not sure I understand you simplified question. You want to generate a boundary mesh and for that you need to give all cords and connectivity, To boundary mesh does not provide geometric operations such as splitting boundary elements.

Comment: @user21 Sorry if my comment is unclear. I would like to mesh(triangle)  a `Rectangle[]` with the constraint that all meshpoints on the diagonal are predefined via "IncludePoints".

Comment: @user21 ...and no elementside should cross the diagonal. The mesh should be a fullmesh in 2D

Comment: IncludePoints works with ToElementMesh and not with ToBoundaryMesh. IncludePoints need to be inside the region and not in the boundary.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, maybe something like [addVertex from this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257815/125)?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, looks promising, I have to check carefully...

Comment: @user21: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html at Option IncludePoints it is clearly written, that "These additional points are considered to be part of the boundary, but need not be on the actual boundary."

Comment: @wvt_beginner, what that means is that all include points are addressable in, say, DirichletCondition but they can not be generated on the boundary. I'll clarify that statement in a future release. So it means that you can have a DirichletCondition (a *boundary* condition) inside the region. All points you want on the geometric boundary need to be specified through the coordinates and connectivity in ToBoundaryMesh

Comment: @wvt_beginner, I have clarified the documentation about the usage of "IncludePoints" This will be available in the 14.1 release (not in the imminent 14.0 release though). Thanks for pointing this out. I have other sections in the documentation that you feel are unclear, let me know and I'll see if I can improve them. Thx.

Comment: @user21: thanks for the update!

Answer (score 4):

Another method to achieve helical mesh.

```
m = 15;
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 + #5 &}, Mesh -> 2 m + 1, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 + #5 &, #4 - #5 &}, Mesh -> 2 m + 1, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 + #5 &, #4 - #5 &, #4 &, #5 &}, 
 Mesh -> 2 m + 1, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is about generation an ElementMesh, how do you propose to move from your answer to that?

Comment: @user21: The OP original title/question: "How to mesh a cylinder with helix points?". That is what my answer provides - a helix mesh of a cylinder.

Comment: -1. This is a question and answer site not a title and answer site. So you read a title of a book and you know the content?

Answer (score 2):

```
       ParametricPlot3D[{40 Cos[ \[Phi]], 40 Sin[ \[Phi]], 
           z + 2.85 \[Phi] }, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, -100, 100}, 
                Mesh -> { 0, 10}, 
                    MeshStyle -> Directive[{ Red, Thickness[0.01]}], 
                  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Helixed cylinder]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I asked for a special meshing of a cylinder.