# Numerically solve 2nd order ordinary differential equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

```
ℒ = -1/2 Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + V[x] u[x]; 

sort[
 NDEigenvalues[
   ℒ, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 5, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}
 ]
]
```

I am trying  to solve numerically a 2nd order ordinary differential equation. This does not work with *Mathematica* 10.00?

Comment: Please format your post for better readability. See e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting.

Comment: What is the definition of `V[x]`?

Answer (score 1):

`NDEigensystem` was added in version 10.2 (or was it 10.3?) but version 10.0 is not going to work unless you use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56305/18437).