# Comparing analytical solution with numerical solution of Helmholtz equation in a unit square

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I am just learning PDE, and I am interested to compare analytical solution with numerical solution of Helmholtz equation in a unit square with zero boundary condition. I am not sure if it possible. Below is the equation I am analyzing, with its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions:
    $$
\begin{cases}
\Delta^2u+\lambda u=0,\\
u(0,y)=0,\quad u(x,0)=0,\\
u(1,y)=0,\quad u(x,1)=0,
\end{cases}
$$
I found out from a textbook that the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are:
$\lambda_{nm}=(n^2+m^2)\pi^2$ and $u_{nm}=\sin n\pi x \sin m\pi y$, where $n,m=1,2,3,\ldots$.
I know that the solution to the above equation is trivial, i.e., $u=0$. However, I found from [question regarding solution to Helmholtz by other user](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56305/numerically-solving-helmholtz-equation-in-2d-for-arbitrary-shapes), that we can solve the equation in term of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues. So, in my case, the first six eigenfunctions are

```
region = Rectangle[];
{eigenvalues[region], eigenfunctions[region]} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + u[x, y], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] region, 6];
Grid[Partition[Table[Show[{ContourPlot[eigenfunctions[region][[j]], {x, y} \[Element] region, Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotPoints -> 60, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> eigenvalues[region][[j]]],RegionPlot[region, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}]}], {j, 1, Length[eigenvalues[region]]}], 3]]
```

[image: solution].

I wonder if I can do error analysis by suming the eigenfunctions and compare it with $u=0$ in $L_2$ norm.

1) But, what is the exact analytical solution of this equation in terms of eigenfunctions? I know it is the summation of those eigenvalues, but I am not sure how to sum it.

2) And, how to sum those first six images of eigenfunctions with mathematica? Once somebody show me how to sum those images, I think I can do the error analysis myself. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I am not exactly sure I understand what you are trying to do. Maybe you are looking for an eigenfunction expansion? There is an example of this in the documentation of [NDEigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) in the section Applications and then Eigenfunction Expansion. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the solution to the above equation is trivial, which is $u=0$. However, if I am not wrong we can also get solution by adding the eigenfunctions? So I plan to do error analysis, for example I want to compare the exact analytical solution, which is $u=0$ with the sum of eigenfunctions. I assume the more eigenfunctions we add, the smaller the error is? I am just learning PDE, so that is what my understanding is. I am not sure if it is correct. So for example, if mathematica gives me these six eigenfunctions, how to add those functions?

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. $u=0$ is $u_{nm}$ with $n=m=0$. No sum just one term, no error too. However, what is the significance of this solution?  The Helmholtz equation describes some physical process and for this matter $u=0$ is to be neglected.

Comment: The $u$ that I mean is the final analytical solution, i,e,, when the $m,n$ is infinite. Is it possible? Or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Note 1 that the solution also depends on initial conditions.  You have to supply two. 2 you have chosen a square which due to symmetry will sometimes have identical eigenvalues. See your second and third eigenvectors.  These need special treatment when combining them. A rectangle is simpler.

Comment: Hi Hugh, thanks a lot for the input about the difference between square and rectangle. I wonder, if it is rectangle, is it possible to combine the eigenfunctions from Mathematica to the final solution $u$?

Comment: Lila, you should have a look at the example I referenced above, that shows how eigenfunctions are added.

Comment: Hi user21, I already checked the documentation of NDEigensystem, but it only show how to get the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. I don't see the part about how eigenfunctions are added. Actually, I am starting to wonder, if it is possible? I mean, for more complex shapes, should we just satisfied with the solution which consist of separate eigenfunctions?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not that familiar with this topic, so feel free to point out if I'm wrong.

I think the trivial solution simply cannot be represented by a combination of eigenfunctions, the reason is as follows.

Let's add a constant inhomengeneous term $s$ to the equation

$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta^2u+\lambda u=s,\\
u(0,y)=0,\quad u(x,0)=0,\\
u(1,y)=0,\quad u(x,1)=0,
\end{cases}
$$

and solve it with the help of [`finiteFourierSinTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871). (I don't use `DSolve` here because it doesn't represent the solution in terms of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues. )

First, interpret the system to *Mathematica* code:

```
With[{u = u[x, y]}, eq = Laplacian[u, {x, y}] + lambda u == s;
 bc = u == 0 /. List /@ Flatten@Outer[Rule, {x, y}, {0, 1}]]
```

Then make transform on $x$ and $y$:

```
ffst = finiteFourierSinTransform;
Format@ffst[f_, __] := Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF], s][f]

{teq, tbc} = ffst[{eq, bc[[3 ;; 4]]}, {x, 0, 1}, n] /. Rule @@@ bc[[1 ;; 2]]

tteq = ffst[teq, {y, 0, 1}, m] /. ffst[ffst[a_, b__], c__] :> ffst[ffst[a, c], b] /. 
  Rule @@@ tbc
```

Finally solve for the transformed solution and transform back:

```
ttsol = u[x, y] /. First@Solve[tteq /. ffst[ffst[a_, b__], c__] :> a, u[x, y]]

tsol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[ttsol, n, {x, 0, 1}]

sol = HoldForm@Sum[#, {n, C@1}, {m, C@2}] &[
  inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, m, {y, 0, 1}] //. HoldForm@Sum[a_, __] :> a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Apparently, as long as $s$ is a non-zero number, the particular solution for the problem can be represented by a combination of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues, but when $s=0$, every summand becomes zero. That's the reason why I think eigenfunctions and eigenvalues can't represent this zero solution.

Finally, a image taken at $\lambda=1\,,s=1$:

```
Plot3D[sol //. {lambda -> 1, s -> 1, C@_ -> 6, 
     HoldPattern@Sum[a__] :> Total@Flatten@Table@a} // ReleaseHold // Evaluate, {x, 0, 
  1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Since I read somewhere that the solution to the above is infinite sum of eigenfunctions, so add the solutions: starting by adding the first 2 eigenfunctions, then 3, until 6. I notice that after each addition, the image is getting lighter, which means it is closer to the analytical solution $u=0$. So, the more eigenfunctions, the error is smaller. Please correct me if I am wrong. (I don't know how to enter the code using code command, since it involves images).
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you add images, not the functions? Notice also that if $u_{nm}$ is an eigenfunction, so does the rescaled one $\alpha u_{nm}$. They both correspond to the same eigenvalue $\lambda_{mn}$. So why not adding with prefactors? Where does your formula about the summation coming from?

Comment: I add the images since I thought the image represent the eigenfunctions. I add images since I want to analyze it numerically with the solution from Mathematica, which is the eigenfunctions? So you think it is not possible to use the images from Mathematica? I know the analytical solution, which involves the functions and prefactors. I just want to compare analytical and numerical solution which involves eigenfunctions.

Comment: This method for adding solutions is wrong, just add the same picture for several times and you'll know what I mean. The correct way is e.g. `Plot3D[eigenfunctions[region] // Total // Evaluate, {x, y} \[Element] region]`, which clearly shows that the naive summation isn't getting closer to `0`.