# How to control DifferenceOrder in NDEigenvalue for an ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve the eigenvalue problem of a 1st-order ODE system using NDEigenvalue. It should be finite difference method for ODE. And I want to tune the the `DifferenceOrder` and also the number of mesh points.
The relevant option I found in `NDEigenvalue` seems to be `PDEDiscretization` that probably descretizes the spatial part and in my case there's only a spatial part. After some searching, I still cannot find the correct way to set the `DifferenceOrder` and the number of mesh points.

The following is my stupid try (the particular ODE maybe not so important for this question?)

```
eps0 = 1*^-10; points = 500;
f[R_, r_] := Exp[r/R] - 1(*Tan[π/2r/R]*); 
m0[R_, r_] := 1.0/R f[R, r]; A[l_, B_, r_] := l/r + B/2 r;
Fop1[y_, l_, pm_] := I (-D[y, r] + pm A[l, B, r] y);
variables = {α, β, γ, δ};
lhs = {Fop1[δ[r], l + 1, -1] + kz γ[r] + 
    m0[R, r] α[r], 
   Fop1[γ[r], l, 1] - kz δ[r] + m0[R, r] β[r], 
   Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + kz α[r] - 
    m0[R, r] γ[r], 
   Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - kz β[r] - m0[R, r] δ[r]};
bc = DirichletCondition[
  Table[component@r == 0, {component, variables}], True]

l = -2; R = 2; B = 20; kz = 2; Rcutoff = 
 1.0 Min[6 R, 16/Sqrt[B]]; Nless = 50;
Re@NDEigenvalues[{lhs, bc}, variables, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",  
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> points, "MinPoints" -> points, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. <strike>`"MethodOfLines"` is a method for solving well-posed initial-boundary value problem so we can't use it for eigenvalue problem.</strike> Despite actually being used (see the comments below for more details), `"MethodOfLines"` isn't an option for `NDEigenvalue`.
2. Though `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative `` facilitates self-implementation of finite difference method (FDM), FDM hasn't been implemented in `NDSolve` and its friends so far, that's the reason why I wrote [`pdetoode`/`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).
3. At the moment, `NDEigenvalue` together with `NDEigensystem` are based on `"FiniteElement"` method only. The option amounts to difference order of FDM is `"MeshOrder"`, which unfortunately cannot be higher than `2` up to now.

So, in short, it's not possible to use FDM in `NDEigenvalue` etc., at least now.

Comment: The first point is not quite correct. In fact we use "MethodOfLines" for *every* PDE when using `NDEigensystem`. This is shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437).

Comment: It should be possible to adapt the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437) to use the FDM approach.

Comment: @user21 Er… I think you've mis-pasted the link in the first comment? (It's the same as the one in the second comment. )

Comment: Yes, they are the same link. The point is that every PDE given to NDEigensystem is transformed into a time dependent PDE.

Comment: Thanks! Let's see if there would be any other answer. So you mean `NDEigenvalues` uses difference order 2 in FEM sense. Hmm,,, It gives the same pattern as `DifferenceOrder` 4 in the FDM based on your code (the `DifferenceOrder` dependent problem I mentioned previously). Probably I will post a separate question simply addressing this strange problem itself.