# How can NDSolveValue and ParametricNDSolveValue be used correctly to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, numerics, finite-element-method

`NDEigensystem` can be used to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the following system $H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}$.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
rmax = 20;
HH = -(1/2)*Laplacian[u[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] - 
   1/r*u[r];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{HH + u[r]}, u[r], {r, 0, rmax}, 50, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.015}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];
Sort[vals] - 1
(*{-0.5, -0.125018, -0.0616851, -0.0225138, 0.0582443, 0.168841, \
0.306885, 0.471408, 0.661866, 0.877922, 1.11936, 1.38602, 1.6778, \
1.99462, 2.33642, 2.70316, 3.09479, 3.51129, 3.95264, 4.41881, \
4.9098, 5.42558, 5.96614, 6.53148, 7.12159, 7.73645, 8.37606, \
9.04042, 9.72952, 10.4434, 11.1819, 11.9452, 12.7332, 13.546, \
14.3834, 15.2456, 16.1325, 17.0441, 17.9804, 18.9414, 19.9271, \
20.9375, 21.9727, 23.0325, 24.117, 25.2263, 26.3602, 27.5188, \
28.7021, 29.9101}*)
funs[[1 ;; 5]]
```

Is it possible to get eigenfunctions and eigenvalues using `NDSolveValue` or `ParametricNDSolveValue`? How can this be implemented? \

```
-(1/2)*Laplacian[u[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] - 
  1/r*u[r] == EE*u[r]
```

Do I understand correctly that eigenvalue `EE` is a parameter in this case? What two conditions should be written for a function `u[r]`?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

rmax = 20;

ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(1/2)*
     Laplacian[u[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] - 1/r*u[r] ==
    EE*u[r], u[0] == 1}, u, {r, 0, rmax}, {EE}]
```

Comment: **Is it possible to get eigenfunctions and eigenvalues using NDSolveValue** No. If it was possible, then there would not be need for `NDEigensystem`. Let look at ode first. The problem is $y''(x) = -\lambda y(x)$  with some boundary conditions, for example $y(0)=0,y(L)=0$. Other combinations of BC are possible. The $\lambda$ are the values that permit solutions given these BC. each corresponding solution is called eigenfunction.   Same goes for Laplacian. $\Delta u = -\lambda u$ but the difference is we are in 2D now and BC are on the whole boundary. To obtain the $\lambda$ in this case....

Comment: ... the standard way is to use separation of variables and obtain the spatial ode and apply the BC now on this ode and find the $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenfunctions (which are solutions now to the spatial odes).   To do all this, special code is needed. That is why `NDSovle` or `DSolve` do not do this.

Comment: See how NDEigensystem is implemented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437)

Comment: @Nasser, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @user21, thanks for the link!