# Inner working of `NDEigensystem`

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

What is the inner workings of the `NDEigensystem`? How does it solve a second-order differential equation?

I know it is an inbuilt Mathematica function. I want to know the code behind this function so I can control my calculation manually.

Comment: That's explained in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56305/numerically-solving-helmholtz-equation-in-2d-for-arbitrary-shapes) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56305/numerically-solving-helmholtz-equation-in-2d-for-arbitrary-shapes) post.