# Mathematica Crashes with low memory warning Trying to solve Schroedinger Equation in a box with initial constraints

Tags: differential-equations

```
\[Psi] = u /. 
   First@NDSolve[{I D[u[t, x, y], t] == -D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] - 
        D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}], 
      u[0., x, y] == 
       Sqrt[1/1.98944]*1/(2*Pi*0.2^2)*
        Exp[-1/2*((x^2)/0.2^2 + (y)^2/0.2^2)], 
      u[t, -5., y] == u[t, 5., y] == u[t, x, -5.] == u[t, x, 5.] == 
       0}, u, {t, 0., 2.}, {x, -5., 5.}, {y, -5., 5.}, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
     MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

when I try to evaluate this, it runs for maybe 15minutes, gobbles up all available ram and then crashes. Is there any way for me to fix it (putting constraints on how much memory mathematica can acess) or better yet, a more efficient way of doing these calculations? if I dont force the boundary conditions to be 0, this evaluates in a blink of an eye.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ee4LqXRlQmE at 3min in this video you see what I am trying to plot.

I created this with the help of Jens solution. I just increased the number of points and Plotted the Probablity Density (Read psi^2) 
[wavegif](http://makeagif.com/VQTOJu)
thx again Jens, Im still trying go wrap my head around how your code works exactly:) Im not all that used to the Mathematica syntax yet

Im mostly having trouble following you where you define your c[] array (I assume fourier coefficients?) and I think I dont quite understand what is happening when you use [#,#2]

Awesome answer thx!

Comment: What you did here is take the approach from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27996/245) and made two changes: narrowed the initial wave packet, requiring a lot more spatial points for an accurate discretization, and changed the boundary conditions from periodic to Dirichlet, which is inconsistent with the [pseudospectral method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-spectral_method).

Comment: A more efficient approach for this simple example would be to expand in eigenfunctions of the time-independent equation with Dirichlet conditions.

Comment: Oh I didnt mean to pretend I came up with all of this on my own, yes I also normalized the wavefunction so that psi^2 integrated = 1. thanks for pointing out the problem with pseudospectral method. Im not sure I understand you on your second point. this was ment to be more of a demo problem to calculate more difficult problems later on. so for general solutions to the 2-d particle in a box problem wouldnt I need the time dependant version? say for an arbitrary normalized psi[x,y,0]?

Comment: I would not mind long computation times btw. If I can run it over night id be fine with it

Comment: Maybe I can add some more explanations later. The `Array` with slots `#` is a shorter way of constructing one of the lists I need. You could do the same with another `Table` construct. `Array` is just shorter sometimes, especially here since it doesn't require me to define an additional table index variable. The slots `#` and `#2` are then the stand0ins for the table indices I didn't want to name.

Comment: What im now trying to plot is what you gave me, but with my old normalized wavefunction (normal curve instead of gaussian), I realize that I took a rather narrow function (its been calculating the better part of an hour), should this finish? my main problem with the distribution you use is, that I dont know how to normalize it (I think it shifts if it isnt centered on 0 and I scale it?)

Comment: basically there is a theorem that states, that if you can Normalize the wavefunction so that Integrate psi^2[x,y,0] dy dx == 1 then the wavefunction will stay normalized for all of t. So to use it for any sort of probabalistic analysis, I have to normalize the wavefunction

Comment: Normalization factors are irrelevant in a linear differential equation, so you can add any scaling you want after the calculation of $\psi$, instead of cluttering up the solution process with numerical constants. It's always best in numerics to reduce the number of parameters to the minimum relevant set. The consistent way of normalizing the result is to do an integral over the absolute square of the *result* at an arbitrary time over the box, and divide by the square root of that number. For *plotting* a movie with normalization, you additionally have to fix the color scale.

Comment: my point is that there should only be 1 such normalization constant for all of t, but youre ofcourse right about linearity, I can just scale the result of your equation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no spatially or temporally varying potential energy term in the differential equation, it's not efficient to apply `NDSolve` with the method of lines. The Dirichlet boundary conditions are in principle also inconsistent with the Gaussian initial condition, so one should choose an initial condition that is forced to be zero at the boundary. The narrow initial packet requires a large spatial grid.

To get around this, it's better to expand in the known eigenfunctions of the time-independent Schrödinger equation for the box. Here is a function that does this:

```
Options[evolve2D] = {PlotPoints -> 10}; 
evolve2D[ψinitial_, {x_, xMin_, xMax_}, {y_, yMin_, yMax_}, t_, 
  OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {lx, ly, n, δ, data, ψBox, basis, dim, c, amplitudes},
  lx = xMax - xMin;
  ly = yMax - yMin;
  ψBox[μ_, ν_] := 
   Sin[(μ Pi (x - xMin))/lx] Sin[(ν Pi (y - yMin))/ly];
  n = OptionValue[PlotPoints];
  δ = N[Min[lx, ly]/n];
  data = Table[{x, y, ψinitial}, {x, xMin + δ/2, 
     xMax, δ}, {y, yMin + δ/2, yMax, δ}];
  dim = Most[Dimensions[data]];
  basis = Flatten[Array[c[#, #2] ψBox[#, #2] &, dim]];
  amplitudes = Flatten[Array[c[#, #2] &, dim]];
  Total[basis Flatten[
      Array[Exp[-I t ((#/lx)^2 + (#2/ly)^2)] &, dim]]] /. 
   FindFit[Flatten[data, 1], Total[basis], amplitudes, {x, y}]
  ]

ψ = evolve2D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/.2^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, t, 
   PlotPoints -> 30];

frames = Table[
   DensityPlot[Evaluate[Re[ψ]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
    PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
    ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"],
   {t, 0, 12, .1}];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: frames]

The majority of the time is spent making the plots. The actual computation is very fast.

`evolve2D` is specially written for a rectangular box with Dirichlet boundary conditions, and it uses the known wave functions and energies for that problem.

You give it an arbitrary initial condition, that **doesn't even have to be consistent with the boundary conditions.** The function will take care of adapting the initial condition to an allowed form automatically. This works by using `FindFit`:

The initial condition is converted to a table of initial `data` on a grid of sampling points that are supposed to be chosen so they don't coincide with the nodal lines of the eigenfunctions $\psi_{\mu,\nu}(x,y)$. Then I ask `FindFit` to give me a set of expansion coefficients such that a superposition of eigenfunctions reproduces the given initial data in the best possible way. At that stage any conflict with the boundary conditions is removed, because the resulting fit of the initial data will always satisfy them, at the expense of introducing some deviation from the initial function in the domain, if necessary.

The range of indices for the eigenfunctions in my expansion is determined by the dimensions of the data grid representing the initial values. I.e., the number of basis functions with unknown coefficients is equal to the number of initial data given by the initial wave function. The number of sampling points is determined by the option `PlotPoints`.

Once I have the fit, the time evolution of the wave consists simply of multiplying each term in the eigenfunction superposition by its time-evolution factor $\exp(-i t E_{\mu,\nu})$ in dimensionless units (chosen such that the energies are simply $E_{\mu,\nu} = (\mu/L_x)^2+ (\nu/L_y)^2$, where $L_x$ and $L_y$ are the dimensions of the rectangular box.

Comment: thank you so much for that detailed answer, it helps a lot. A minor detail. since its a wavefunction you'd probably want to plot psi*Conjugate[psi] to get a plot of the probability density of the electrons position. I have to read trough all of this carefully now

Comment: @catadoxas Sure, you can replace the `Re` by `Abs[Psi]^2` if you prefer. In a more streamlined answer, one could also replace my `FindFit` approach with a Fourier series. But the advantage of using function fitting is that it can be generalized more easily to other systems where the eigenfunctions don't happen to be identical to sine waves, i.e., basis functions of the Fourier series. You could use the same method to plot wave packet evolution in a 2D harmonic oscillator, for example. One then would fit the initial packet to a superposition of HO eigenfunctions.