# NDSolve for complex pde

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, complex

My goal is to use `NDSolve` to solve the complex pde $F(z,t)$ with complex derivative $\partial_{z}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{x}-i \partial_{y}).$ The equation can be solved by `DSolve`:

```
pde = I*D[F[z, t], t] -z*D[F[z, t], z] == 0
sol = DSolve[pde, F[z, t], {z, t}]
pde = I*D[F[z, t], t] -z*D[F[z, t], z] == 0
sol = DSolve[{pde, F[z, 0] == Exp[z]}, F[z, t], {z, t}]
```

[image: image of code above and solution returned by DSolve]

One can see the solution is $F(z,t)=e^{-e^{it}z}$.

In the future, however, I will have more complicated cases on which `DSolve` may fail, so I want to solve it using `NDSolve` as well.  I change $z=x+iy$ and implement the complex derivative, but it fails and the function looks incorrect:
[image: NDSolve returns warnings on missing boundary conditions and failed error tolerance check]

I think this is because I didn't specify the boundary conditions for the grid, but how can I know it? I expected that the condition  $F(x,y,0)=F(z,0)=e^{z}$ would have been enough, as it was for `DSolve`.
How can solve this issue?

Comment: The question is unclear to me.  Why replace `z` by `x + I y`?  If you do need to make this substitution, write `F` as `F[`x + I y, t]`.

Comment: I just copy here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/complex-valued-21d-pde-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-numerical-method-for-ndsolve. Is that True that NDsolve can solve complex pde?

Comment: If I replace anything with z, ndsolve can only specify the region of z, like {z,-4,4}. But this also fails.

Comment: Before trying to solve for `F[x,y,0}`, try solving `NDSolve[{pde, F[z, 0] == Exp[z]}, F[z, t], {z, -4, 4}, {t, 0, 2}]`.  You need to specify boundary conditions in `x` and perhaps also add artificial viscosity.  By the way, is the equation you ultimately wish to solve also first order?

Comment: NO, it is second order and can not be solved using Dsolve, so this is why I want to solve it using NSolve.

Comment: 1. Please add the code text of `NDSolve[…]` to the question. If you're having difficulty in formating it, see this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/1871 2. "I expected that the condition $F(x,y,0)=F(z,0)=e^z$ would have been enough, as it was for `DSolve`." That's because in `DSolve` the i.c. is defined in the whole domain, but that's not the case for `NDSolve`. Observe the output of e.g. `DSolve[{pde, F[z, 0] == Piecewise[{{Exp[z], -1 < Re@z < 1 && -1 < Im@z < 1}}, unknown]}, F, {z, t}]` and think about why. 3. Can you add some background info of the problem?